# How do you display JavaScript datetime in 12 hour AM/PM format?

Tags: javascript, datetime, date, time, format

How do you display a JavaScript datetime object in the 12 hour format (AM/PM)?

Comment: Don't waste your time http://stackoverflow.com/a/17538193/3541385 its working..

Comment: @Ritesh `WARNING: toLocaleTimeString() may behave differently based on region / location.` Measure twice, cut once.

Comment: @AbandonedCart is that actually a saying?

Answer (score 801, accepted):

```js
function formatAMPM(date) {
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
  return strTime;
}

console.log(formatAMPM(new Date));
```

Answer (score 438):

If you just want to show the hours then..

```js
var time = new Date();
console.log(
  time.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', hour12: true })
);
```

Output : 7 AM

If you wish to show the minutes as well then...

```js
var time = new Date();
console.log(
  time.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true })
);
```

Output : 7:23 AM

Comment: What about hour, minutes, and AM/PM?

Comment: As of Feb 2018 its working just fine on chrome Neolisk - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#Browser_compatibility

Comment: it should return 07:23, IMO

Comment: @HumbleDolt You might be confusing `'numeric'` with `'2-digit'`.

Comment: @Katie in 2019 too

Comment: Source: https://caniuse.com/#search=toLocaleString() - "...supported in effectively all browsers (since IE6+, Firefox 2+, Chrome 1+ etc)"

Comment: this is the best answer but how do you change the capitalization of AM/PM

Comment: Great answer! Here's a link to the MDN docs for information on the options if anyone needs it: [`Intl.DateTimeFormat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat)

Comment: @hon2a hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit'

Answer (score 51):

Here's a way using regex:

```js
console.log(new Date('7/10/2013 20:12:34').toLocaleTimeString().replace(/([\d]+:[\d]{2})(:[\d]{2})(.*)/, "$1$3"))
console.log(new Date('7/10/2013 01:12:34').toLocaleTimeString().replace(/([\d]+:[\d]{2})(:[\d]{2})(.*)/, "$1$3"))
```

This creates 3 matching groups:

- `([\d]+:[\d]{2})` - Hour:Minute
- `(:[\d]{2})` - Seconds
- `(.*)` - the space and period (Period is the official name for AM/PM)

Then it displays the 1st and 3rd groups.

**WARNING: toLocaleTimeString() may behave differently based on region / location.**

Comment: People don't use Regex enough.  This worked for me without adding the jquery/microsoftajax library suggestions above.

Comment: What would be the regex be to have a trailing zero at the beginning of the hour if it was a single digit. Say in your first example of 8:12 PM it would be 08:12 PM?

Comment: @404 it's the same, `([\d]+:[\d]{2})` is the part we are interested in. Use the colon (:) as the separator and we see the first part is `[\d]+`. The plus means one or more. So it's looking for one or more digit (including zero. If you had to guarantee a zero is there, it would be `(0[\d]:[\d]{2})`. This now reads, look for 0 plus one other digit, then colon, then the rest.

Comment: console.log(new Date().toLocaleTimeString().replace(/([\d]+:[\d]{2})(:[\d]{2})(.*)/, "$1$3")); To get current time

Comment: Doesn't work in Australia.  `new Date('7/10/2013 20:12:34').toLocaleTimeString()` gives `20:12:34`, and regex just gave `20:12`.  @abhay-kumar answer `time.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true })` worked.

Answer (score 50):

If you don't need to print the am/pm, I found the following nice and concise:

```
var now = new Date();
var hours = now.getHours() % 12 || 12;  // 12h instead of 24h, with 12 instead of 0.
```

This is based off @bbrame's answer.

Comment: @koolinc for midnight it shows 12. I'm not sure what else the desired behavior would be.

Comment: I stand corrected. In my country the 24-hour clock is used, so I'm not that familiar with the 12-hour clock. Indeed midnight is 12:00am.

Comment: This method is perfect if need only hour in 12 hr format

Answer (score 37):

In **modern browsers,** use `Intl.DateTimeFormat` and force 12hr format with options:

```
    let now = new Date();

    new Intl.DateTimeFormat('default',
        {
            hour12: true,
            hour: 'numeric',
            minute: 'numeric'
        }).format(now);

    // 6:30 AM
```

Using `default` will honor browser's default locale if you add more options, yet will still output 12hr format.

Comment: to use this, assign the new string to a variable eg:
let result = new Intl.DateTi....
alert(result);

Comment: Can also do: `const time = new Date().toLocaleString([], { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' });  //"6:30 AM"`

Answer (score 34):

As far as I know, the best way to achieve that without extensions and complex coding is like this:

```
     date.toLocaleString([], { hour12: true});
```

[Javascript AM/PM Format](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FC47DLHGIVH6)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p>Click the button to display the date and time as a string.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <button onclick="fullDateTime()">Try it2</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p id="demo2"></p>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var d = new Date();
            var n = d.toLocaleString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' });
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
        }
        function fullDateTime() {
            var d = new Date();          
            var n = d.toLocaleString([], { hour12: true});
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = n;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I found this checking this question out.

[How do I use .toLocaleTimeString() without displaying seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913681/how-do-i-use-tolocaletimestring-without-displaying-seconds)

Comment: This is the most simple answer. Vote up because is a javascript native solution. Thanks

Comment: This is a nice native solution.

Answer (score 23):

Use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) for this

Use below codes in JavaScript when using moment.js

```
H, HH       24 hour time
h, or hh    12 hour time (use in conjunction with a or A)
```

The `format()` method returns the date in specific format.

```
moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"); // 24H clock
moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm A"); // 12H clock (AM/PM)
moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm a"); // 12H clock (am/pm)
```

Comment: This 12H format saved my day, thanks.

Answer (score 20):

My suggestion is use moment js for date and time operation.

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

```js
console.log(moment().format('hh:mm a'));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 19):

Updated for more compression

```
const formatAMPM = (date) => {
  let hours = date.getHours();
  let minutes = date.getMinutes();    
  const ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';

  hours %= 12;
  hours = hours || 12;    
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes;

  const strTime = `${hours}:${minutes} ${ampm}`;

  return strTime;
};

console.log(formatAMPM(new Date()));
```

Comment: Its working fine
Thanks

Answer (score 15):

use `dateObj.toLocaleString([locales[, options]])`

**Option 1** - Using locales

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US'));
```

**Option 2** - Using options

```
var options = { hour12: true };
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-GB', options));
```

**Note:** supported on all browsers but safari atm

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString

Answer (score 13):

Short RegExp for en-US:

```
var d = new Date();
d = d.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:\d+ /, ' '); // current time, e.g. "1:54 PM"
```

Comment: this doesn´t work on latest safari and firefox browsers, time still uses 24 hour format

Comment: answers get outdated as time goes by. Feel free to edit and update!

Comment: This actually will make the string look like `1:54 PM CDT`.  To remove the `CDT` alter your regex to the following `.replace(/:\d+ |\CDT/g, ' ')`.   Although, CDT is just my timezone. If you have a different timezone I suppose you would need to change to that zone code.

Comment: The output of [*toLocaleTimeString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.tolocaletimestring) is implementation dependent, so not reliably the same format everywhere.

Answer (score 12):

Please find the solution below

```
var d = new Date();
var amOrPm = (d.getHours() < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";
var hour = (d.getHours() < 12) ? d.getHours() : d.getHours() - 12;
return   d.getDate() + ' / ' + d.getMonth() + ' / ' + d.getFullYear() + ' ' + hour + ':' + d.getMinutes() + ' ' + amOrPm;
```

Comment: Should be less than or equal to for hour calculation else noon shows up as 0.  So: var hour = (d.getHours() <= 12).   Still has issue with midnight so you have to check if zero then set to 12 too.

Answer (score 9):

It will return the following format like

```
09:56 AM
```

appending zero in start for the hours as well if it is less than 10

Here it is using ES6 syntax

```js
const getTimeAMPMFormat = (date) => {
  let hours = date.getHours();
  let minutes = date.getMinutes();
  const ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  hours = hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours;
  // appending zero in the start if hours less than 10
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
  return hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
};
console.log(getTimeAMPMFormat(new Date)); // 09:59 AM
```

Answer (score 6):

I fount it's [here](https://shashikantbhosale.wordpress.com/2013/07/17/javascript-convert-24-hour-clock-time-format-to-12-hour-time-clock-format/) it working fine.

```
var date_format = '12'; /* FORMAT CAN BE 12 hour (12) OR 24 hour (24)*/
 
 
var d       = new Date();
var hour    = d.getHours();  /* Returns the hour (from 0-23) */
var minutes     = d.getMinutes();  /* Returns the minutes (from 0-59) */
var result  = hour;
var ext     = '';
 
if(date_format == '12'){
    if(hour > 12){
        ext = 'PM';
        hour = (hour - 12);
        result = hour;

        if(hour < 10){
            result = "0" + hour;
        }else if(hour == 12){
            hour = "00";
            ext = 'AM';
        }
    }
    else if(hour < 12){
        result = ((hour < 10) ? "0" + hour : hour);
        ext = 'AM';
    }else if(hour == 12){
        ext = 'PM';
    }
}
 
if(minutes < 10){
    minutes = "0" + minutes; 
}
 
result = result + ":" + minutes + ' ' + ext; 
 
console.log(result);
```

and plunker example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpwfPm7pEoGeDcf2IYYL?p=preview)

Answer (score 6):

Hopefully this answer is a little more readable than the other answers (especially for new comers).

Here's the solution I've implemented in some of my sites for informing the last time the site code was modified. It implements AM/PM time through the `options` parameter of `date.toLocaleDateString` ([see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) related Mozilla documentation).

```js
// Last time page code was updated/changed
const options = {
    year: "numeric",
    month: "long",
    weekday: "long",
    day: "numeric",
    hour: "numeric",
    minute: "numeric",
    second: "numeric",
    hour12: true // This is the line of code we care about here
    /*
        false: displays 24hs format for time
        true: displays 12, AM and PM format
    */
};

let last = document.lastModified;
let date = new Date(last);
let local = date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
let fullDate = `${local}`;
document.getElementById("updated").textContent = fullDate;
```

Which output is in the format:

```bash
Saturday, May 28, 2022, 8:38:50 PM
```

This output is then displayed in the following HTML code:

```html
<p>Last update: <span id="updated">_update_date_goes_here</span></p>
```

NOTE: In this use case, `document.lastModified` has some weird behaviors depending if it's run locally or on a external server ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665656/javascript-document-lastmodified-is-returning-current-date-and-time) this Stack Overflow question). Though it works correctly when I run it in my GitHub page (you should see it in action in the site at the [footer](https://carloswm85.github.io/)).

Answer (score 5):

Check out [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/). Their built in formatters can do this: http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#toString

It's a really handy library, especially if you are planning on doing other things with date objects.

Comment: Answers like "*use library X*" are not helpful. They can be good as comments though.

Comment: @RobG: As you can see it's been quite a while since I wrote this answer. I realize this now.

Answer (score 5):

```
<script>
var todayDate = new Date();
var getTodayDate = todayDate.getDate();
var getTodayMonth =  todayDate.getMonth()+1;
var getTodayFullYear = todayDate.getFullYear();
var getCurrentHours = todayDate.getHours();
var getCurrentMinutes = todayDate.getMinutes();
var getCurrentAmPm = getCurrentHours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
getCurrentHours = getCurrentHours % 12;
getCurrentHours = getCurrentHours ? getCurrentHours : 12; 
getCurrentMinutes = getCurrentMinutes < 10 ? '0'+getCurrentMinutes : getCurrentMinutes;
var getCurrentDateTime = getTodayDate + '-' + getTodayMonth + '-' + getTodayFullYear + ' ' + getCurrentHours + ':' + getCurrentMinutes + ' ' + getCurrentAmPm;
alert(getCurrentDateTime);
</script>
```

Comment: Getting the module of the hour with 12 is excellent! This prevents getting zero when it's 12AM or it's 12PM

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way that is simple, and very effective:

```
        var d = new Date();

        var weekday = new Array(7);
        weekday[0] = "Sunday";
        weekday[1] = "Monday";
        weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
        weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
        weekday[4] = "Thursday";
        weekday[5] = "Friday";
        weekday[6] = "Saturday";

        var month = new Array(11);
        month[0] = "January";
        month[1] = "February";
        month[2] = "March";
        month[3] = "April";
        month[4] = "May";
        month[5] = "June";
        month[6] = "July";
        month[7] = "August";
        month[8] = "September";
        month[9] = "October";
        month[10] = "November";
        month[11] = "December";

        var t = d.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:\d+ /, ' ');

        document.write(weekday[d.getDay()] + ',' + " " + month[d.getMonth()] + " " + d.getDate() + ',' + " " + d.getFullYear() + '<br>' + d.toLocaleTimeString());

    </script></div><!-- #time -->
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have time as string like so `var myTime = "15:30"`,
then you can use the following code to get am pm.

```
var hour = parseInt(myTime.split(":")[0]) % 12;
var timeInAmPm = (hour == 0 ? "12": hour ) + ":" + myTime.split(":")[1] + " " + (parseInt(parseInt(myTime.split(":")[0]) / 12) < 1 ? "am" : "pm");
```

Comment: just what i need !

Comment: @derarsattouf The pervious code had issue with 00:00 and 24:00, i have fixed that. please update your code with the above if you had used this

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is looking for a 1-liner:

```js
const formatAMPM = date => `${(date.getHours() % 12) || 12}:${date.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0')} ${date.getHours() < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM'}`
```

OR more readable 3-liner (or if you don't have `padStart` in your browser):

```js
const formatAMPM = (date) => {
  let minutes = date.getMinutes()
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes
  return `${(date.getHours() % 12) || 12}:${minutes} ${date.getHours() < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM'}`
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function startTime() {
  const today = new Date();
  let h = today.getHours();
  let m = today.getMinutes();
  let s = today.getSeconds();
  var meridian = h >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
  h = h % 12;
  h = h ? h : 12;
  m = m < 10 ? "0" + m : m;
  s = s < 10 ? "0" + s : s;
  var strTime = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + meridian;
  document.getElementById('time').innerText = strTime;
  setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
}

startTime();
```

```html
<h1 id='time'></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can determine am or pm with this simple code

```
var today=new Date();
var noon=new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate(),12,0,0);
var ampm = (today.getTime()<noon.getTime())?'am':'pm';
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
      var date = new Date();
      var hours = date.getHours();
      var minutes = date.getMinutes();
      var seconds = date.getSeconds();
      var ampm = hours >= 12 ? "pm" : "am";
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The hours could be greater than 12.

Comment: When 12.00 pm the var ampm will be "pm". So 12.00 PM to 11.00 PM hours will be 12 to 23 that store "pm" value and for others, var ampm will store "am" value. Hope you understand.

Comment: Hi Juyel ! Indeed when the hours is greater than 12, the value would be PM. But the question is "How do you display JavaScript datetime in 12 hour AM/PM format?" - you need to help OP convert the entire time to the AM/PM format. 

For example, 14:30 would be 2:30 PM.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function formatTime( d = new Date(), ampm = true ) 
{
    var hour = d.getHours();
    
    if ( ampm )
    {
        var a = ( hour >= 12 ) ? 'PM' : 'AM';
        hour = hour % 12;
        hour = hour ? hour : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'  
    }

    var hour    = checkDigit(hour);  
    var minute  = checkDigit(d.getMinutes());
    var second  = checkDigit(d.getSeconds());
  
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript
    return ( ampm ) ? `${hour}:${minute}:${second} ${a}` : `${hour}:${minute}:${second}`;
}

function checkDigit(t)
{
  return ( t < 10 ) ? `0${t}` : t;
}

document.querySelector("#time1").innerHTML = formatTime();
document.querySelector("#time2").innerHTML = formatTime( new Date(), false );
```

```html
<p>ampm true:   <span id="time1"></span> (default)</p>
<p>ampm false:  <span id="time2"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   const formatAMPM = (date) => {
    try {
      let time = date.split(" ");
      let hours = time[4].split(":")[0];
      let minutes = time[4].split(":")[1];
      hours = hours || 12;
      const ampm = hours >= 12 ? " PM" : " AM";
      minutes = minutes < 10 ? `${minutes}` : minutes;
      hours %= 12;
      const strTime = `${hours}:${minutes} ${ampm}`;
      return strTime;
    } catch (e) {
      return "";
    }
  };

const startTime = "2021-12-07T17:00:00.073Z"
formatAMPM(new Date(startTime).toUTCString())
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var d = new Date();
var hours = d.getHours() % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12;
    var test = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'][(d.getMonth() + 1)] + " " + 
    ("00" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + " " + 
    d.getFullYear() + " " + 
    ("00" + hours).slice(-2) + ":" + 
    ("00" + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + 
    ("00" + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2) + ' ' + (d.getHours() >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM'); 
    
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = test;
```

```html
<p id="demo" ></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1 id="clock_display" class="text-center" style="font-size:40px; color:#ffffff">[CLOCK TIME DISPLAYS HERE]</h1>



<script>
            var AM_or_PM = "AM";

            function startTime(){

                var today = new Date();
                var h = today.getHours();
                var m = today.getMinutes();
                var s = today.getSeconds();

                h = twelve_hour_time(h);
                m = checkTime(m);
                s = checkTime(s);



                document.getElementById('clock_display').innerHTML =
                    h + ":" + m + ":" + s +" "+AM_or_PM;
                var t = setTimeout(startTime, 1000);

            }

            function checkTime(i){

                if(i < 10){
                    i = "0" + i;// add zero in front of numbers < 10
                }
                return i;
            }

            // CONVERT TO 12 HOUR TIME. SET AM OR PM
            function twelve_hour_time(h){

                if(h > 12){
                    h = h - 12;
                    AM_or_PM = " PM";
                }
                return h;

            }

            startTime();

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution

```
function getTime() {
var systemDate = new Date();
var hours = systemDate.getHours();
var minutes = systemDate.getMinutes();
var strampm;
if (hours >= 12) {
    strampm= "PM";
} else {
    strampm= "AM";
}
hours = hours % 12;
if (hours == 0) {
    hours = 12;
}
_hours = checkTimeAddZero(hours);
_minutes = checkTimeAddZero(minutes);
console.log(_hours + ":" + _minutes + " " + strampm);
}

function checkTimeAddZero(i) {
if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
}
return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDateTime() {
  var now = new Date();
  var year = now.getFullYear();
  var month = now.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = now.getDate();

  if (month.toString().length == 1) {
    month = '0' + month;
  }
  if (day.toString().length == 1) {
    day = '0' + day;
  }

  var hours = now.getHours();
  var minutes = now.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12;
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
  var timewithampm = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;

  var dateTime = monthNames[parseInt(month) - 1] + ' ' + day + ' ' + year + ' ' + timewithampm;
  return dateTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest Way you can Achieve this using ternary operator or you can also use if else instead !

```
const d = new Date();
let hrs = d.getHours();
let m = d.getMinutes();
// Condition to add zero before minute
let min = m < 10 ? `0${m}` : m;
const currTime = hrs >= 12 ? `${hrs - 12}:${min} pm` : `${hrs}:${min} am`;
console.log(currTime);
```

Comment: this gives 12pm as 0:00pm.

Answer (score 0):

{new Date(progress.position * 1000).toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' }).substring(0,5)}

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<header class="is-sticky">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="customNav">
                    <ul class="navMenuWeb">
                        <li><Link to="#">At a Glance</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="#">Deposit</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="#">Loan</Link></li>
                        <li><Link to="#">Products & Offers</Link></li>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
.is-sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: .95s ease-in-out 0s normal none 1 running fadeInDown;
  animation: .95s ease-in-out 0s normal none 1 running fadeInDown;
  z-index: 999;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  transition: all 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Or just simply do the following code:

```
    <script>
        time = function() {
            var today = new Date();
            var h = today.getHours();
            var m = today.getMinutes();
            var s = today.getSeconds();
            m = checkTime(m);
            s = checkTime(s);
            document.getElementById('txt_clock').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;     
            var t = setTimeout(function(){time()}, 0);
        }

        time2 = function() {
            var today = new Date();
            var h = today.getHours();
            var m = today.getMinutes();
            var s = today.getSeconds();
            m = checkTime(m);
            s = checkTime(s);
            if (h>12) {
                document.getElementById('txt_clock_stan').innerHTML = h-12 + ":" + m + ":" + s;
            }               
            var t = setTimeout(function(){time2()}, 0);
        }

        time3 = function() {
            var today = new Date();
            var h = today.getHours();
            var m = today.getMinutes();
            var s = today.getSeconds();
            if (h>12) {
                document.getElementById('hour_line').style.width = h-12 + 'em'; 
            }
            document.getElementById('minute_line').style.width = m + 'em';  
            document.getElementById('second_line').style.width = s + 'em';  
            var t = setTimeout(function(){time3()}, 0);
        }

        checkTime = function(i) {
            if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
            return i;
        }           
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

A short and sweet implementation:

```
// returns date object in 12hr (AM/PM) format
var formatAMPM = function formatAMPM(d) {
    var h = d.getHours();
    return (h % 12 || 12)
        + ':' + d.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0')
        + ' ' + (h < 12 ? 'A' : 'P') + 'M';
};
```