# How to get AM or PM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I have buttons with the names of big cities.
Clicking them, I want to get local time in them.

```
$('#btnToronto').click(function () {
    var hours = new Date().getHours();
    var hours = hours-2; //this is the distance from my local time
    alert ('Toronto time: ' + hours + ' h'); //this works correctly
});
```

But how can I get AM or PM ?

Comment: Mmmm... divide by 12? modulo?

Comment: @elclanrs, `hours` is for example `19`. Divide by 12... what?

Comment: if `hours < 12` so it is PM , otherwise it is AM , no?

Comment: @SunSky: lol. I messed up, my bad. I posted my answer tho, hope that helps.

Comment: Why would you think you should subtract two hours? That makes no sense.  The date you get back from `new Date()` will already be in your local time, unless your computer's time zone setting is wrong.  And if you were thinking about time zone offsets from UTC, Toronto is `-0500` during standard time and `-0400` during daylight time. It's never `-0200`. And `.getHours()` returns the hours in local time anyway.

Comment: I have given the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58892934/6516699. Simply and yet powerful

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try below code:

```
$('#btnToronto').click(function () {
    var hours = new Date().getHours();
    var hours = (hours+24-2)%24; 
    var mid='am';
    if(hours==0){ //At 00 hours we need to show 12 am
    hours=12;
    }
    else if(hours>12)
    {
    hours=hours%12;
    mid='pm';
    }
    alert ('Toronto time: ' + hours + mid);
});
```

Comment: Confused, but I will try all the solutions. Solved (I hope).

Comment: What happens if the time is before 2 a.m. before adjusting hours?

Comment: This code is incorrect for 12:00 pm.  In that case, you need to leave hours set to 12, but change mid to 'pm'.

Answer (score 42):

You should just be able to check if hours is greater than 12.

```
var ampm = (hours >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM";
```

But have you considered the case where the hour is less than 2 before you subtract 2?  You'd end up with a negative number for your hour.

Comment: Consider: is midnight _a.m._ or _p.m._ ? What does that mean for noon? What will this say noon is?

Comment: @PaulS. Quite right - fixed for noon.  Midnight should come back as 0  and should be am, so that at least should have worked.

Answer (score 13):

You can use like this,

```
var dt = new Date();
    var h =  dt.getHours(), m = dt.getMinutes();
    var _time = (h > 12) ? (h-12 + ':' + m +' PM') : (h + ':' + m +' AM');
```

Hopes this will be better with minutes too.

Comment: This doesn't work with the hour of 12 noon unfortunately. Times are PM when hours >= 12, but you only subtract 12 when hours >= 13

Answer (score 10):

```
const now = new Date()
      .toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', hour12: true })
      .toLowerCase();
```

Basically you just need to put **{hour12: true}** and it's done.

> result => now = "21:00 pm";

Answer (score 4):

If `hours` is less than `12`, it's the *a.m.*.

```
var hours = new Date().getHours(), // this is local hours, may want getUTCHours()
    am;
// adjust for timezone
hours = (hours + 24 - 2) % 24;
// get am/pm
am = hours < 12 ? 'a.m.' : 'p.m.';
// convert to 12-hour style
hours = (hours % 12) || 12;
```

Now, for me as you didn't use `getUTCHours`, it is currently 2 hours after

```
hours + ' ' + am; // "6 p.m."
```

Answer (score 4):

very interesting post. in a function that take a date in parameter it can appear like that :

```
function hourwithAMPM(dateInput) {
   var d = new Date(dateInput);
   var ampm = (d.getHours() >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM";
   var hours = (d.getHours() >= 12) ? d.getHours()-12 : d.getHours();

   return hours+' : '+d.getMinutes()+' '+ampm;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

with date.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.datejs.com/build/date.js"></script>
```

you can write like this

```
new Date().toString("hh:mm tt")
```

cheet sheet is here [format specifiers](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers#toString_(available_in_core.js_))

`tt` is for `AM/PM`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
h = h > 12 ? h-12 +'PM' : h +'AM';
```

Comment: Consider; is 12:30 (noon) am or pm? What will this code say it is?

Answer (score 2):

The best way without extensions and complex coding:

```
date.toLocaleString([], { hour12: true});
```

[How do you display javascript datetime in 12 hour AM/PM format?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41852604/4967502)

Answer (score 1):

here is get time i use in my code

```
let current = new Date();
let cDate = current.getDate() + '-' + (current.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + current.getFullYear();
let hours = current.getHours();
let am_pm = (hours >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM";

if(hours >= 12){
    hours -=12;
}

let cTime = hours + ":" + current.getMinutes() + ":" + current.getSeconds() +" "+ am_pm;
let dateTime = cDate + ' ' + cTime;

console.log(dateTime);   // 1-3-2021 2:28:14 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var now = new Date();
var hours = now.getHours();
var minutes = now.getMinutes();
var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
hours = hours % 12;
hours = hours ? hours : 12;
minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
var timewithampm = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
return timewithampm;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var dt = new Date();
var h = dt.getHours(),
  m = dt.getMinutes();
var time;
if (h == 12) {
  time = h + ":" + m + " PM";
} else {
  time = h > 12 ? h - 12 + ":" + m + " PM" : h + ":" + m + " AM";
}
//var time = h > 12 ? h - 12 + ":" + m + " PM" : h + ":" + m + " AM";

console.log(`CURRENT TIME IS ${time}`);
```

This will work for everytime,

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Timer() {
    var dt = new Date()
    if (dt.getHours() >= 12){
        ampm = "PM";
    } else {
        ampm = "AM";
    }
    if (dt.getHours() < 10) {
        hour = "0" + dt.getHours();
    } else {
        hour = dt.getHours();
    }
    if (dt.getMinutes() < 10) {
        minute = "0" + dt.getMinutes();
    } else {
        minute = dt.getMinutes();
    }
    if (dt.getSeconds() < 10) {
        second = "0" + dt.getSeconds();
    } else {
        second = dt.getSeconds();
    }
    if (dt.getHours() > 12) {
        hour = dt.getHours() - 12;
    } else {
        hour = dt.getHours();
    }
    if (hour < 10) {
        hour = "0" + hour;
    } else {
        hour = hour;
    }
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + " " + ampm;
    setTimeout("Timer()", 1000);
}
Timer()
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```