# How to show only hours and minutes from javascript date.toLocaleTimeString()?

Tags: javascript, date

Can anyone please help me get the `HH:MM am/pm` format instead of `HH:MM:SS am/pm`.

My javascript code is :

```js
function prettyDate2(time){
  var date = new Date(parseInt(time));
  var localeSpecificTime = date.toLocaleTimeString();
  return localeSpecificTimel;
}
```

It returns the time in the format `HH:MM:SS am/pm`, but my client's requirement is `HH:MM am/pm`.

Please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use .toLocaleTimeString() without displaying seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913681/how-do-i-use-tolocaletimestring-without-displaying-seconds)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

A more general version from [@CJLopez's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20430558/2539605):

```
function prettyDate2(time) {
  var date = new Date(parseInt(time));
  return date.toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute:'2-digit'
  });
}
```

**Original answer** (not useful internationally)

You can do this:

```
function prettyDate2(time){
    var date = new Date(parseInt(time));
    var localeSpecificTime = date.toLocaleTimeString();
    return localeSpecificTime.replace(/:\d+ /, ' ');
}
```

The regex is stripping the seconds from that string.

Comment: bear in mind that for non english locale, this solution won't work, as the regex of \d won't detect the numbers. Example: `date.toLocaleTimeString('ar')`. Therefore, _@Dan Cron_ 's answer is better for general use.

Comment: This doesn't work for Finnish or German locales, as the separator symbol is "." (dot) not ":". @Dan Cron's answer is better.

Comment: This is a bad answer, and should be deleted, for the reasons above.

Answer (score 67):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913681/how-do-i-use-tolocaletimestring-without-displaying-seconds) is a more general version of this question, which covers locales other than en-US. Also, there can be issues parsing the output from toLocaleTimeString(), so CJLopez suggests using this instead:

```
var dateWithouthSecond = new Date();
dateWithouthSecond.toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'});
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) library.

```
 function prettyDate2(time){
    var date = new Date(parseInt(time));
    var options = {hour: "numeric", minute: "numeric"};
    return new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", options).format(date);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

I posted my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48595422/6204133

```
var textTime = new Date(sunriseMills + offsetCityMills + offsetDeviceMills) 
                .toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' });
```

//  '7.04 AM'

Answer (score 1):

You may also try like this:-

```
function timeformat(date) {
  var h = date.getHours();
  var m = date.getMinutes();
  var x = h >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  h = h % 12;
  h = h ? h : 12;
  m = m < 10 ? '0'+m: m;
  var mytime= h + ':' + m + ' ' + x;
  return mytime;
}
```

or something like this:-

```
new Date('16/10/2013 20:57:34').toLocaleTimeString().replace(/([\d]+:[\d]{2})(:[\d]{2})(.*)/, "$1$3")
```