# How to convert time in milliseconds to hours, min, sec format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, milliseconds

I have a time as a number of milliseconds and I want to convert it to a `HH:MM:SS` format. It should wrap around, with `milliseconds = 86400000` I want to get `00:00:00`.

Answer (score 207):

How about creating a function like this:

```js
function msToTime(duration) {
  var milliseconds = Math.floor((duration % 1000) / 100),
    seconds = Math.floor((duration / 1000) % 60),
    minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
    hours = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

  hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
  minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

  return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + "." + milliseconds;
}
console.log(msToTime(300000))
```

Comment: I have used this way for convert milliseconds to hours:minutes:seconds format.but i did not get it correctly.it is giving only 21:11:05 for  all milliseconds.how can i implement this?

Comment: var s = st_date+' '+start;
  var e = end_date+' '+end;
  var bits = s.split(/\D/);
  var bits1 = e.split(/\D/);
  var date = new Date(bits[0], --bits[1], bits[2], bits[3], bits[4],bits[5]);
  var date1 = new Date(bits1[0], --bits1[1], bits1[2], bits1[3], bits1[4],bits1[5]);

Comment: var t1=date.getTime()
  var t2=date1.getTime()
  var t3=date1.getTime()-date.getTime();
  
  
  
  var seconds;
  var minutes;
  var milliseconds = parseInt((t3%1000)/100)
    , seconds = parseInt((t3/1000)%60)
            , minutes = parseInt((t3/(1000*60))%60)
            , hours = parseInt((t3/(1000*60*60))%24);

        hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

  duration=hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
  alert('dur::'+t3);
  alert('duration:'+duration);

Comment: that is my code for your consideration.please check it and help me.thanks in advance....

Comment: If duration input param is already in milliseconds, why do you divide by 100 to get milliseconds? Shouldn't it be just parseInt(duration % 1000)?

Comment: can anyone tell me why dividing milliseconds by 100 ?

Comment: @akashpatel @NoBullMan the `/ 100` is throwing out everything past 1/10th of a second precision. So `msToTime(100)` returns `00:00:00.1` and `msToTime(99)` returns `'00:00:00.0'`

Comment: should be `var milliseconds = Math.floor(duration % 1000),`

Comment: This is a great answer. However, it does truncate the ms when < 1000. Rewriting `milliseconds = Math.floor((duration % 1000) / 100)` as `milliseconds = Math.floor(duration % 1000)` fixes this

Comment: I think this will go into my copy-paste library. Very good! Thanks!

Comment: how about for days ?

Comment: Found this comment from the Youtube code base, they have commented this in their code

Answer (score 90):

To Convert time in millisecond to human readable format.

```js
function msToTime(ms) {
  let seconds = (ms / 1000).toFixed(1);
  let minutes = (ms / (1000 * 60)).toFixed(1);
  let hours = (ms / (1000 * 60 * 60)).toFixed(1);
  let days = (ms / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)).toFixed(1);
  if (seconds < 60) return seconds + " Sec";
  else if (minutes < 60) return minutes + " Min";
  else if (hours < 24) return hours + " Hrs";
  else return days + " Days"
}

console.log(msToTime(1000))
console.log(msToTime(10000))
console.log(msToTime(300000))
console.log(msToTime(3600000))
console.log(msToTime(86400000))
```

[image: "Out Put Sample"]

Comment: I found this one the most useful, the top answer didn't seem to handle hours very well in my testing and this also gives you the options of days.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you.

Comment: To me this answer is not helpful. What does "3.7" hours mean???

Answer (score 34):

I had the same problem, this is what I ended up doing:

```js
function parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime(milliseconds){
  //Get hours from milliseconds
  var hours = milliseconds / (1000*60*60);
  var absoluteHours = Math.floor(hours);
  var h = absoluteHours > 9 ? absoluteHours : '0' + absoluteHours;

  //Get remainder from hours and convert to minutes
  var minutes = (hours - absoluteHours) * 60;
  var absoluteMinutes = Math.floor(minutes);
  var m = absoluteMinutes > 9 ? absoluteMinutes : '0' +  absoluteMinutes;

  //Get remainder from minutes and convert to seconds
  var seconds = (minutes - absoluteMinutes) * 60;
  var absoluteSeconds = Math.floor(seconds);
  var s = absoluteSeconds > 9 ? absoluteSeconds : '0' + absoluteSeconds;


  return h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
}


var time = parseMillisecondsIntoReadableTime(86400000);

alert(time);
```

Answer (score 26):

Here is my solution

```
let h,m,s;
h = Math.floor(timeInMiliseconds/1000/60/60);
m = Math.floor((timeInMiliseconds/1000/60/60 - h)*60);
s = Math.floor(((timeInMiliseconds/1000/60/60 - h)*60 - m)*60);
```

// to get time format 00:00:00

```
s < 10 ? s = `0${s}`: s = `${s}`
m < 10 ? m = `0${m}`: m = `${m}`
h < 10 ? h = `0${h}`: h = `${h}`


console.log(`${s}:${m}:${h}`);
```

Comment: I'd set value to s outside the ternary operator: `s = \`${s < 10 ? '0': ''}${s}\` `

Answer (score 23):

This one returns time like youtube videos

```
    function getYoutubeLikeToDisplay(millisec) {
        var seconds = (millisec / 1000).toFixed(0);
        var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        var hours = "";
        if (minutes > 59) {
            hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
            hours = (hours >= 10) ? hours : "0" + hours;
            minutes = minutes - (hours * 60);
            minutes = (minutes >= 10) ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
        }

        seconds = Math.floor(seconds % 60);
        seconds = (seconds >= 10) ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
        if (hours != "") {
            return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
        }
        return minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
```

Output:

- getYoutubeLikeToDisplay(129900) = "2:10"
- getYoutubeLikeToDisplay(1229900) = "20:30"
- getYoutubeLikeToDisplay(21229900) = "05:53:50"

Comment: comment - does not work correctly for negative time for example `-3000` should show `-00:03` but it returns `-1:0-03`.

Comment: I made some improvements/adjustments https://stackoverflow.com/a/67462589

Answer (score 18):

Sorry, late to the party. The accepted answer did not cut it for me, so I wrote it myself.

Output:

```
2h 59s
1h 59m
1h
1h 59s
59m 59s
59s
```

Code (Typescript):

```
function timeConversion(duration: number) {
  const portions: string[] = [];

  const msInHour = 1000 * 60 * 60;
  const hours = Math.trunc(duration / msInHour);
  if (hours > 0) {
    portions.push(hours + 'h');
    duration = duration - (hours * msInHour);
  }

  const msInMinute = 1000 * 60;
  const minutes = Math.trunc(duration / msInMinute);
  if (minutes > 0) {
    portions.push(minutes + 'm');
    duration = duration - (minutes * msInMinute);
  }

  const seconds = Math.trunc(duration / 1000);
  if (seconds > 0) {
    portions.push(seconds + 's');
  }

  return portions.join(' ');
}

console.log(timeConversion((60 * 60 * 1000) + (59 * 60 * 1000) + (59 * 1000)));
console.log(timeConversion((60 * 60 * 1000) + (59 * 60 * 1000)              ));
console.log(timeConversion((60 * 60 * 1000)                                 ));
console.log(timeConversion((60 * 60 * 1000)                    + (59 * 1000)));
console.log(timeConversion(                   (59 * 60 * 1000) + (59 * 1000)));
console.log(timeConversion(                                      (59 * 1000)));
```

Comment: Thanks man, this is what I wanted. Had to adapt slightly to show '0h 0m 10s' etc but otherwise clean and simples

Comment: I started writing my own, then I thought, somebody must have done this already :). Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

The above snippets don't work for cases with more than 1 day (They are simply ignored).

For this you can use:

```
function convertMS(ms) {
    var d, h, m, s;
    s = Math.floor(ms / 1000);
    m = Math.floor(s / 60);
    s = s % 60;
    h = Math.floor(m / 60);
    m = m % 60;
    d = Math.floor(h / 24);
    h = h % 24;
    h += d * 24;
    return h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
}
```

[image]

Thanks to https://gist.github.com/remino/1563878

Comment: To have more humanized output you can return something like: return ((h + '').length === 1 ? '0'+ h : h) + ':' + ('0' + m).substr(-2) + ':' + ('0' + s).substr(-2);

Comment: @Vitall Just use `return (h < 10 ? "0" + h : h) + ":" + (m < 10 ? "0" + m : m) + ":" + (s < 10 ? "0" + s : s);`, because it's way better doing this with math than a bunch of string manipulation.

Answer (score 7):

I needed time only up to one day, 24h, this was my take:

```js
const milliseconds = 5680000;

const hours = `0${new Date(milliseconds).getHours() - 1}`.slice(-2);
const minutes = `0${new Date(milliseconds).getMinutes()}`.slice(-2);
const seconds = `0${new Date(milliseconds).getSeconds()}`.slice(-2);

const time = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`
console.log(time);
```

you could get days this way as well if needed.

Answer (score 6):

#### Format as `hh:mm:ss` with optional padding

(`1:59:59` or `01:59:59`)
(`1:59` or `01:59`)
*(Default: no padding)*

Based loosely on [Chand's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37168679).

```
function formatMilliseconds(milliseconds, padStart) {
    function pad(num) {
        return `${num}`.padStart(2, '0');
    }
    let asSeconds = milliseconds / 1000;

    let hours = undefined;
    let minutes = Math.floor(asSeconds / 60);
    let seconds = Math.floor(asSeconds % 60);

    if (minutes > 59) {
        hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
        minutes %= 60;
    }

    return hours
        ? `${padStart ? pad(hours) : hours}:${pad(minutes)}:${pad(seconds)}`
        : `${padStart ? pad(minutes) : minutes}:${pad(seconds)}`;
}
```

Tests:

```
let s = 1000;
let m = 60*s;
let h = 60*m;
console.log(formatMilliseconds(1*h));               // 1:00:00
console.log(formatMilliseconds(1*h, true));         // 01:00:00
console.log(formatMilliseconds(59*m + 59*s));       // 59:59
console.log(formatMilliseconds(59*m + 59*s, true)); // 59:59
console.log(formatMilliseconds(9*m + 9*s));         // 9:09
console.log(formatMilliseconds(9*m + 9*s, true));   // 09:09
console.log(formatMilliseconds(5*s));               // 0:05
console.log(formatMilliseconds(5*s, true));         // 00:05
console.log(formatMilliseconds(2400*s));            // 40:00
console.log(formatMilliseconds(2400*s, true));      // 40:00
```

.
.
.
If you need millisecond precision, you can get the fractional part using the following:

```
(asSeconds % 1).toFixed(3).substring(1)
```

Your returns would end up looking like this (break it up for readability as necessary):

```
`${padStart ? pad(hours) : hours}:${pad(minutes)}:${pad(seconds)}${(asSeconds % 1).toFixed(3).substring(1)}`
```

There are probably better ways to do that, but this naive solution gets the job done.

Test:

```
let asSeconds = 59.5219;
let seconds = Math.floor(asSeconds);
console.log(`${pad(seconds)}${(asSeconds % 1).toFixed(3).substring(1)}`);
// Equivalent to above, without using `pad()`:
//console.log(`${String(seconds).padStart(2, '0')}${(asSeconds % 1).toFixed(3).substring(1)}`);

// Output: 59.522
```

Comment: This doesn't fulfill OP's requirement of 24 hours wrapping around to 00:00:00 (but then aren't you expressing a time on the clock rather than a duration?)

Comment: This is probably a more sensible and idiomatic way to get just the decimal plus 3 digits: secondString = asSeconds.toFixed(3);
secondString.substring(secondString.indexOf('.'));

Answer (score 5):

This solution uses one `function` to split milliseconds into a `parts object`, and another `function` to format the `parts object`.

I created 2 format functions, one as you requested, and another that prints a friendly string and considering singular/plural, and includes an option to show milliseconds.

```js
function parseDuration(duration) {
  let remain = duration

  let days = Math.floor(remain / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))
  remain = remain % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)

  let hours = Math.floor(remain / (1000 * 60 * 60))
  remain = remain % (1000 * 60 * 60)

  let minutes = Math.floor(remain / (1000 * 60))
  remain = remain % (1000 * 60)

  let seconds = Math.floor(remain / (1000))
  remain = remain % (1000)

  let milliseconds = remain

  return {
    days,
    hours,
    minutes,
    seconds,
    milliseconds
  };
}

function formatTime(o, useMilli = false) {
  let parts = []
  if (o.days) {
    let ret = o.days + ' day'
    if (o.days !== 1) {
      ret += 's'
    }
    parts.push(ret)
  }
  if (o.hours) {
    let ret = o.hours + ' hour'
    if (o.hours !== 1) {
      ret += 's'
    }
    parts.push(ret)
  }
  if (o.minutes) {
    let ret = o.minutes + ' minute'
    if (o.minutes !== 1) {
      ret += 's'
    }
    parts.push(ret)

  }
  if (o.seconds) {
    let ret = o.seconds + ' second'
    if (o.seconds !== 1) {
      ret += 's'
    }
    parts.push(ret)
  }
  if (useMilli && o.milliseconds) {
    let ret = o.milliseconds + ' millisecond'
    if (o.milliseconds !== 1) {
      ret += 's'
    }
    parts.push(ret)
  }
  if (parts.length === 0) {
    return 'instantly'
  } else {
    return parts.join(' ')
  }
}

function formatTimeHMS(o) {
  let hours = o.hours.toString()
  if (hours.length === 1) hours = '0' + hours

  let minutes = o.minutes.toString()
  if (minutes.length === 1) minutes = '0' + minutes

  let seconds = o.seconds.toString()
  if (seconds.length === 1) seconds = '0' + seconds

  return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds
}

function formatDurationHMS(duration) {
  let time = parseDuration(duration)
  return formatTimeHMS(time)
}

function formatDuration(duration, useMilli = false) {
  let time = parseDuration(duration)
  return formatTime(time, useMilli)
}


console.log(formatDurationHMS(57742343234))

console.log(formatDuration(57742343234))
console.log(formatDuration(5423401000))
console.log(formatDuration(500))
console.log(formatDuration(500, true))
console.log(formatDuration(1000 * 30))
console.log(formatDuration(1000 * 60 * 30))
console.log(formatDuration(1000 * 60 * 60 * 12))
console.log(formatDuration(1000 * 60 * 60 * 1))
```

Answer (score 5):

I recently ran into this situation. My focus was on clean readability and reusability.

## Use

(See function definition below)

```
timeUnits(86400000) // {days: 1, hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0, ms: 0}
```

Then you can use the data to do whatever you want (like build a string).

**Other examples:**

```
timeUnits(214870123) // {days: 2, hours: 11, minutes: 41, seconds: 10, ms: 123}
```

```
timeUnits('70123') // null
```

## Function

```
/**
 * Converts milliseconds into greater time units as possible
 * @param {int} ms - Amount of time measured in milliseconds
 * @return {?Object} Reallocated time units. NULL on failure.
 */
function timeUnits( ms ) {
    if ( !Number.isInteger(ms) ) {
        return null
    }
    /**
     * Takes as many whole units from the time pool (ms) as possible
     * @param {int} msUnit - Size of a single unit in milliseconds
     * @return {int} Number of units taken from the time pool
     */
    const allocate = msUnit => {
        const units = Math.trunc(ms / msUnit)
        ms -= units * msUnit
        return units
    }
    // Property order is important here.
    // These arguments are the respective units in ms.
    return {
        // weeks: allocate(604800000), // Uncomment for weeks
        days: allocate(86400000),
        hours: allocate(3600000),
        minutes: allocate(60000),
        seconds: allocate(1000),
        ms: ms // remainder
    }
}
```

It's written in such a way so that you can easily implement other units (for example, where I commented out implementation for weeks) so long as you know their worth in milliseconds.

Answer (score 4):

// The following is written in Typescript, should be easy to translate to JS

```
function humanReadableDuration(msDuration: int): string {
    const h = Math.floor(msDuration / 1000 / 60 / 60);
    const m = Math.floor((msDuration / 1000 / 60 / 60 - h) * 60);
    const s = Math.floor(((msDuration / 1000 / 60 / 60 - h) * 60 - m) * 60);

    // To get time format 00:00:00
    const seconds: string = s < 10 ? `0${s}` : `${s}`;
    const minutes: string = m < 10 ? `0${m}` : `${m}`;
    const hours: string = h < 10 ? `0${h}` : `${h}`;

    return `${hours}h ${minutes}m ${seconds}s`;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me

```
msToTime(milliseconds) {
    //Get hours from milliseconds
    var hours = milliseconds / (1000*60*60);
    var absoluteHours = Math.floor(hours);
    var h = absoluteHours > 9 ? absoluteHours : '0' + absoluteHours;

    //Get remainder from hours and convert to minutes
    var minutes = (hours - absoluteHours) * 60;
    var absoluteMinutes = Math.floor(minutes);
    var m = absoluteMinutes > 9 ? absoluteMinutes : '0' +  absoluteMinutes;

    //Get remainder from minutes and convert to seconds
    var seconds = (minutes - absoluteMinutes) * 60;
    var absoluteSeconds = Math.floor(seconds);
    var s = absoluteSeconds > 9 ? absoluteSeconds : '0' + absoluteSeconds;

    return h == "00" ? m + ':' + s : h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Human-readable code for human-readable output and you can extend this to light years or nanoseconds or what have you very intuitively. Obviously you'd want to convert this to a function and re-use some of those intermediate modulo calls.

```
second = 1000 
minute = second * 60
hour = minute * 60 
day = hour * 24

test = 3 * day + 2 * hour + 11 * minute + 58 * second

console.log(Math.floor(test / day))
console.log(Math.floor(test % day / hour))
console.log(Math.floor(test % day % hour / minute))
console.log(Math.floor(test % day % hour % minute / second))
```

Answer (score 3):

Extending on @Rick's answer, I prefer something like this:

```js
function msToReadableTime(time){
  const second = 1000;
  const minute = second * 60;
  const hour = minute * 60;

  let hours = Math.floor(time / hour % 24);
  let minutes = Math.floor(time / minute % 60);
  let seconds = Math.floor(time / second % 60);
 

  return hours + ':' + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
```

Comment: I like this, but what if minutes, for example, is < 10? Can you add padding?

Comment: @ndtreviv, no, it doesn't but you can add it easily, look at Shady's answer

Comment: @ndtreviv padding: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67462589/

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Chand answer. This is the implementation in Typescript. A bit safer than coercing types in JS. If you remove the type annotation should be valid JS. Also using new string functions to normalise the time.

```
function displayTime(millisec: number) {
 const normalizeTime = (time: string): string => (time.length === 1) ? time.padStart(2, '0') : time;

 let seconds: string = (millisec / 1000).toFixed(0);
 let minutes: string = Math.floor(parseInt(seconds) / 60).toString();
 let hours: string = '';

 if (parseInt(minutes) > 59) {
   hours = normalizeTime(Math.floor(parseInt(minutes) / 60).toString());
   minutes = normalizeTime((parseInt(minutes) - (parseInt(hours) * 60)).toString());
 }
 seconds = normalizeTime(Math.floor(parseInt(seconds) % 60).toString());

 if (hours !== '') {
    return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
 }
   return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}
```

Comment: Someone might find it useful.

Comment: JS is evolving towards TypeScript.  This will probably be valid JS soon.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

A [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object can be constructed from milliseconds:

```js
const date = new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, milliseconds);
```

In your question you say milliseconds seconds should 'wrap around' at 86400000. Since we know there are 86400000 milliseconds in a day, we can simply take the time from the date object, and ignore every other part of the date as irrelevant.

The time can then be obtained in any number of formats. The one you require matches that used in the United Kingdom, [locale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString) `en-GB`:

```js
const hms = d.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB');
```

Comment: Clever, but only works for durations <24 hours

Comment: ahh misread op. Upvoted :)

Answer (score 1):

my solution

```
var sunriseMills = 1517573074000;         // sunrise in NewYork on Feb 3, 2018  - UTC time
var offsetCityMills = -5 * 3600 * 1000;   // NewYork delay to UTC 
var offsetDeviceMills =  new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000 ;  // eg. I live in Romania (UTC+2) >> getTimezoneOffset() = 120

var textTime = new Date(sunriseMills + offsetCityMills + offsetDeviceMills) 
    .toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' });
```

textTime will become  '**7.04 AM**'

Comment: This is influenced by your Romania setting in the operating system. I get '7:04 AM'

Answer (score 0):

If you're using typescript, this could be a good thing for you

```
enum ETime {
  Seconds = 1000,
  Minutes = 60000,
  Hours = 3600000,
  SecInMin = 60,
  MinInHours = 60,
  HoursMod = 24,
  timeMin = 10,
}

interface ITime {
  millis: number
  modulo: number
}

const Times = {
  seconds: {
    millis: ETime.Seconds,
    modulo: ETime.SecInMin,
  },
  minutes: {
    millis: ETime.Minutes,
    modulo: ETime.MinInHours,
  },
  hours: {
    millis: ETime.Hours,
    modulo: ETime.HoursMod,
  },
}

const dots: string = ":"

const msToTime = (duration: number, needHours: boolean = true): string => {
  const getCorrectTime = (divider: ITime): string => {
    const timeStr: number = Math.floor(
      (duration / divider.millis) % divider.modulo,
    )

    return timeStr < ETime.timeMin ? "0" + timeStr : String(timeStr)
  }

  return (
    (needHours ? getCorrectTime(Times.hours) + dots : "") +
    getCorrectTime(Times.minutes) +
    dots +
    getCorrectTime(Times.seconds)
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my implementation I used Moment.js:

```
export default (value) => 
  const duration = moment.duration(value);

  const milliseconds = duration.milliseconds();
  const seconds = duration.seconds();
  const minutes = duration.minutes();
  const hours = duration.hours();
  const day = duration.days();

  const sDay = `${day}d `;
  const sHours = (hours < 10) ? `0${hours}h ` : `${hours}h `;
  const sMinutes = (minutes < 10) ? `0${minutes}' ` : `${minutes}' `;
  const sSeconds = (seconds < 10) ? `0${seconds}" ` : `${seconds}" `;
  const sMilliseconds = `${milliseconds}ms`;

  ...
}
```

Once got the strings, I composed them as I want.

Answer (score 0):

> I works for me as i get milliseconds=1592380675409 using javascript method  getTime() which returns the number of milliseconds between midnight of January 1, 1970 and the specified date.

```
var d = new Date();//Wed Jun 17 2020 13:27:55 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
var n = d.getTime();//1592380675409 this value is store somewhere

//function call 
console.log(convertMillisecToHrMinSec(1592380675409));

var convertMillisecToHrMinSec = (time) => {
  let date = new Date(time);
  let hr = date.getHours();
  let min = date.getMinutes();
  let sec = date.getSeconds();

  hr = (hr < 10) ? "0"+ hr : hr;
  min = (min < 10) ? "0"+ min : min;
  sec = (sec < 10) ? "0"+ sec : sec;

  return hr + ':' + min + ":" + sec;//01:27:55
}
```

Comment: Explain your code, code without explanation is bad code.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, i definitely explain my solution

Answer (score 0):

A refactor from @dusht to ES6+ and more functional:

```
const addPrefix = time => time < 10 ? '0' + time : time;
const toHours = time => addPrefix(Math.floor((time / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24));
const toMinutes = time => addPrefix(Math.floor((time / (1000 * 60)) % 60));
const toSeconds = (ime => addPrefix(Math.floor((time / 1000) % 60));
const toMiliseconds = time => Math.floor((time % 1000) / 100);


const milisecondToHoursAndMinute = time => {
  const hours = toHours(time);
  const minutes = toMinutes(time);
  const seconds = toSeconds(time);
  const miliseconds = toMiliseconds(time);

  return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}.${miliseconds}`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let dateTimeStr = new Date(1949778000);
dateTimeStr = Math.floor(dateTimeStr/86400000) +' days '+ dateTimeStr.getHours() +' hours '+ dateTimeStr.getMinutes() +' minutes '+ dateTimeStr.getSeconds() +' seconds';
console.log(dateTimeStr);
```

You don't have to calculate the days if you don't need them

> "22 days 16 hours 36 minutes 18 seconds"

Comment: Beware using this technique as it does not account for timezone offset.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for complication in all these answers, it's easy to add zeros by adding a power of 10:

```
function timeToString(t) {
  const value =
    ((t / 3600_000 % 24) | 0) * 10000 +
    ((t / 60_000 % 60) | 0) * 100 +
    ((t / 1_000 % 60) | 0);
  return (1000000 + value).toString().replace(/1(..)(..)(..)/, '$1:$2:$3');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still need here's a modified version of one of the code snippets posted above in js by https://stackoverflow.com/a/58826445/20067539

```
function timeConversion(duration) { 
    var portions = []; 
    var msInDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
    var days = Math.trunc(duration / msInDay);
    if (days > 0 ) {
        portions.push(days + (days === 1 ? " day" : " days"))
        duration = duration - (days * msInDay)
    }
    var msInHour = 1000 * 60 * 60; 
    var hours = Math.trunc(duration / msInHour);
    if (hours > 0) {
    portions.push(hours + (hours === 1 ? ' hour' : ' hours'));
    duration = duration - (hours * msInHour);
} 
var msInMinute = 1000 * 60; 
var minutes = Math.trunc(duration / msInMinute); 
if (minutes > 0) {
    portions.push(minutes + (minutes === 1 ? ' minute' : ' minutes'));
    duration = duration - (minutes * msInMinute);
}
var seconds = Math.trunc(duration / 1000); 
if (seconds > 0) {
    portions.push(seconds + (seconds === 1 ? ' second' : ' seconds'));
}
return portions.join(' ');
}
console.log(timeConversion((60 * 60 * 1000) + (59 * 60 * 1000) + (59 * 1000)));
console.log(timeConversion((60 * 60 * 1000) + (59 * 60 * 1000)));
console.log(timeConversion((60 * 60 * 1000)));
console.log(timeConversion((60 * 60 * 1000) + (59 * 1000)));
console.log(timeConversion((59 * 60 * 1000) + (59 * 1000)));
console.log(timeConversion((59 * 1000)));
```

Answer (score 0):

"Go's language" [Duration](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Duration) formatting implementation in Typescript

```
const sec = 1000
const min = sec * 60
const hour = min * 60
const day = hour * 24

export function msToDuration(ms: number): string {
    if (ms == 0) {
        return "0s"
    }

    let sign = ''
    if (ms < 0) {
        ms *= -1
        sign = '-'
    }

    const days = ms / day;
    ms = ms % day

    const hours = ms / hour;
    ms = ms % hour

    const minutes = ms / min;
    ms = ms % min

    const seconds = ms / sec;


    let time = seconds.toFixed(3) + "s"

    if (minutes >= 1) {
        time = minutes.toFixed(0) + "m" + time
    }

    if (hours >= 1) {
        time = hours.toFixed(0) + "h" + time
    }

    if (days >= 1) {
        time = days.toFixed(0) + "d" + time
    }

    return sign + time
}
```

Out examples:

```
3d1h10m15.123s
1h10m15.123s
10m15.123s
15.123s
0.123s
0s
```

Answer (score 0):

## Human Readable output:

**e.g. 21 Days, 14 Hrs, 18 Min, 18 Sec, 753 milliseconds.**

Building off of @Nofi's awesome answer for human readable output,
I made a more readable (in my opinion) and accurate version (and less complicated than @Steven Spungin's answer, albeit theirs is really cool) for my personal use and I figured I'd share it here.

```js
function msToTime(ms) {
  let seconds = Math.floor((ms / 1000) % 60);
  let minutes = Math.floor((ms / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
  let hours = Math.floor((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  let days = Math.floor(ms / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  let time = '';
  if (days > 0) {
    time += days + " Days, ";
    ms -= days * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  }
  if (hours > 0) {
    time += hours + " Hrs, ";
    ms -= hours * (1000 * 60 * 60);
  }
  if (minutes > 0) {
    time += minutes + " Min, ";
    ms -= minutes * (1000 * 60);
  }
  if (seconds > 0) {
    time += seconds + " Sec, ";
    ms -= seconds * 1000;
  }
  return time += ms + " milliseconds.";
}
console.log('msToTime(1865898753): \n', msToTime(1865898753));
console.log('msToTime(123456789): \n', msToTime(123456789));
console.log('msToTime(85457): \n', msToTime(85457));
console.log('msToTime(547): \n', msToTime(547));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple typescript function

```
function parseDuration(ms: number) {
    const s = ms < 0 ? 0 : Math.floor(ms / 1000)
    const seconds = Math.floor(s % 60)
    const minutes = Math.floor(Math.floor(s / 60) % 60)
    const hours = Math.floor(s / (60 * 60))

    return {
        seconds,
        minutes,
        hours,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UTCString...

```
let timeStr = new Date(millis).toUTCString().match("..:..:..")[0];
// timeStr = "20:30:22"
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript:

```
public millisecondToString(_milliseconds:number, _seporator:string = ":", _full:boolean = true):string
{
    const ms_d:number = 86400000; //(1000 * 60 * 60 *24)
    const ms_h:number = 3600000;  //(1000 * 60 * 60)
    const ms_m:number = 60000;    //(1000 * 60)
    const ms_s:number = 1000;     //(1000)

    let result:string = "";

    [ms_d, ms_h, ms_m, ms_s].forEach((_mc:number):void=>
    {
        const t:number        = (_milliseconds  / _mc);
        const tt:number       = (t > 0) ? Math.floor(t) : 0;

        if ((_full) || (tt)) result += ((result) ? _seporator : "") + String(tt).padStart(2);

        _milliseconds = _milliseconds - tt * _mc;
    })

    return result;
}
```

result for full, like

```
00:00:12:13
```

result for not full like

```
12:13
```