# Localize "duration" or "time remaining" from milliseconds

Tags: javascript, momentjs, i18next

Let me preface this by saying that I have a "working" solution, taken in part from this previous thread:

> [How to convert time milliseconds to hours, min, sec format in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19700283/how-to-convert-time-milliseconds-to-hours-min-sec-format-in-javascript)

My goal is to take a time duration in milliseconds and convert it to human-readable, using localization/internationalization technologies. The input value is in milliseconds and is a moving target because it is an ETA (estimated time of arrival) rather than a firm time of arrival. It is constantly recalculated.

What I came up with works. What I am looking for is something that might leverage [momentjs](/questions/tagged/momentjs) (because it has a localization system already). It doesn't have to be [momentjs](/questions/tagged/momentjs) in particular, but I want something that has more elegant options, particularly when it comes to localization. I also use and therefore have access to anything provided by [i18next](/questions/tagged/i18next).

Here's a reduced version of the current solution (it's inside an object literal of utility functions):

```js
function duration (millis) {
  // in actual code, a function "i18n.t(key)" would return a properly
  // localized string. Instead, I'll just store English strings in an object
  var mockTranslation = {
    hoursLabel: "hr",
    minutesLabel: "min",
    secondsLabel: "s"
  }

  millis = parseInt(millis);

  function msToTime(duration) {
    var milliseconds = parseInt((duration%1000)/100)
        , seconds = parseInt((duration/1000)%60)
        , minutes = parseInt((duration/(1000*60))%60)
        , hours = parseInt((duration/(1000*60*60))%24);

    hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
    minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    return {
      hours : hours,
      minutes: minutes,
      seconds: seconds,
      milliseconds: milliseconds
    }
  }
  var converted = msToTime(millis);
  var final = "" + converted.hours + " " + mockTranslation.hoursLabel
          + " " + converted.minutes +  " " + mockTranslation.minutesLabel
          + " " + converted.seconds + " " + mockTranslation.secondsLabel;
  return final;
}

// test with a sample input of 416000 ms.
console.log(duration(416000)); // 00 hr 06 min 56 s
```

In this case I take a similar approach as the original thread, but I return a usable object instead of automatically converting to a string. In my real-world code I have some other conditionals I pass through and some options that will return a value that's not localized. But here we see that I take the object and concatenate it with some language entries provided by [i18next](/questions/tagged/i18next). That's where the localization happens.

Yet it seems to me that time durations have more to them than swapping in units of measurement.

Using [momentjs](/questions/tagged/momentjs) seems like overkill, but despite that, I just don't see any duration functions. All date-related functions.

Since I feel that my solution isn't very flexible and that localization is somewhat second-class, does anybody know of a better approach?

Comment: Not sure how to communicate back to the editors other than through comments... but this snippet doesn't actually produce the required output. The intention had to do with localization which is now completely missing. If any of the "approving" editors other than the one rejector ever read this... you failed in your job, too. ;)

Comment: Note: "this snippet" referred to in my previous comment was the one originally provided by an editor. I have since updated it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a possibility to display duration in milliseconds using moment.js in human readable way:

```
moment.duration(416000).humanize();
```

The above code returns: `7 minutes`. Is it what you need?

Of course you can use i18n from moment.js. You just need to call:

```
moment.locale('es');
moment.duration(416000).humanize();
```

to get duration in Spanish localization (`7 minutos`).

If you need more detailed result (`6 minutes 56 seconds`) take a look at this library: https://github.com/EvanHahn/HumanizeDuration.js

Comment: Thank you Marek! Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. I did read the moment docs, but somehow failed to stumble upon either duration or humanize... :-/ More importantly, I believe I need the granularity of HumanizeDuration.js so I must thank you for pointing me in that direction.