# Javascript convert string of time HH:MM:SS in HH:MM

Tags: javascript, time, format

I have a string of time in the format "HH:MM:SS". I want only "HH:MM". How can I do?
For example I have "15:50:30". And I want to obtain with javascript "15:50".

Comment: Would using `Substring` be feasible.

Answer (score 3):

USe substring

```
var date='09:57:22';
date = date.substring(0,5);
```

Comment: @joopmicroop please don't add your two cents to an answer. That's what comments are for.

Answer (score 3):

Use slice

```
"15:50:30".slice(0,-3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 function addZero(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
var d = new Date();
 var h = addZero(d.getHours());
 var m = addZero(d.getMinutes());
 console.log(h + ":" + m )
```

Answer (score 0):

check this link [date to minutes and hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407305/how-to-show-only-hours-and-minutes-from-javascript-date-tolocaletimestring)

```
var dateWithouthSecond = new Date();
dateWithouthSecond.toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily pass the time into get date format.
example.

time ="2:33:58 PM"; your time

pass it to the new date variable.

time = new date (time);

then new time will have the entire date .

then make a string in that get the time and hours .
 time = time.getHours+":"+time.getMinutes

Answer (score 0):

Many of these `slice` and `substring` answers gets the job done, but i would like to point to Regular Expressions as they can be more flexible in regards to inputs.

For instance would this Regular Expression handle both single and double digits, which would throw `slice` and `substring` off:

```js
var tests = ['12:12:12', '1:1:1', '1:12:1', '12:12:1212: 12:12'];
for (var _i = 0, tests_1 = tests; _i < tests_1.length; _i++) {
  var test = tests_1[_i];
  console.log("result of regex on \"" + test + "\" is: \"" + /\d+:\d+/ig.exec(test).shift() + "\"");
}
```