# Javascript format time form date object

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, date, datetime

Currently I'm getting an event start time back from an api response and it looks like this in the html template: `{{ event.start }}` The output of that looks like this: `Mon May 10 2021 06:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)`

How can I format this to only show the time that it has with either **AM** or **PM**: ***6:00 AM*** ?

Comment: This should get you there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407305/how-to-show-only-hours-and-minutes-from-javascript-date-tolocaletimestring

Comment: What about the timezone? Shouldn't ``6`` be transformed accordingly?