# Javascript datetime to inserted in mysqli query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a database set up where landing time requires a datetime data type, and I am trying to pull this off using javascript.

The format looks like the following in the database:

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

My best attempt have been the following:

```
$('#landing_time').val(function(){
      var d = new Date();
      return d.getFullYear() + "-" + d.getMonth() + "-" + d.getDate() + " " + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds() + ":" + d.getMilliseconds();
    });
```

Comment: getMonth returns 0..11 btw

Comment: First of all if take the date from JS it means from client it can be manuplated i recomended do it from server side `NOW()` in sql or in php `date(Y-m-d H:i:s)` if you still want to use JS your problem is in the H:i:s part
H=Hour you are getting miniute
m=minute : you are getting seconds
i= seconds : you are getting miliseconds

Comment: thanks could you kindly elaborate on the javascript part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply wanting to save the time into the database you are better of letting MySQL handle the date by simply inserting `NOW()` into the database query.

However, you can find the answer to your question here: [Format JavaScript Date to yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: hey thanks. .NOW() didnt seem to work for some reason