# Bootstrap date time picker initial value

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker widget to show calendar. But i don't understand how to set initial value from server via js.

I receive value from server in format:

```
Fri, 01 Jan 2016 00:00:00 GMT
```

But all my attempts to set default date failed:

```
$el.datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    defaultDate: moment(this.value, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
})
```

or

```
$el.datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    defaultDate: new Date(this.value)
})
```

> Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This
>   is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please
>   refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.

or

```
$el.datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    defaultDate: moment(new Date(this.value), "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
})
```

> TypeError: defaultDate() Could not parse date parameter: 1029452400000

Comment: can you try to give it as following 
 defaultDate: "15/8/2013"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is a TypeError of the third block, you can try to cover the `this.value` to a "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" format by yourself.

This question may help you to deal with it:

[Format JavaScript Date to yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd)

best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which server side language you are using so assuming it's PHP

First of all the server-side date format is different then then datetimepicker format, you need to change server-side date format to bootstrap datetimepicker format `format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'`;

IF PHP and date is in `Fri, 01 Jan 2016 00:00:00 GMT` Format,

Change it

```
<?php
$sdate = "Fri, 01 Jan 2016 00:00:00 GMT";
$newdate = gmdate("Y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime($sdate));
echo $newdate;
//output will be 2016-01-01 00:01:00
?>
```

Now in JS, create a variable and load the `newdate` and set `defaultDate`

```
var serdate = '2016-01-01 00:01:00';
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
  defaultDate: serdate,
  allowInputToggle: true
});
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ef0muLu9/6/)