# Convert mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I need to convert a date like this, 03/07/2016 to a date format like, 2016-03-07.

How can I do this using javascript or jquery?

Comment: FYI, jQuery *is* Javascript. It's just a library.

Comment: If your input is a string then this is easiest with string methods rather than using Date objects. You could, e.g., use .slice() along with concatenation, or do it in one line with a regex .replace(). What have you tried?

Comment: If you want to use complex logic to work with dates, it is better to use special library such as `momentjs`.

Comment: complex logic like turning ABC into CAB? yeah, better load KBs of code for that...

Comment: The output format in the question title does *not* match the example in the question body. Please [edit] your question to fix whichever is wrong.

Comment: corrected title of question, my mistake

Comment: Here is the answer [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: [This is what you are looking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd) Is JsFiddler you can put you own date formate to test.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming your input is a string, this is easy to do using a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with the [String `.replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
var input = "03/07/2016";
var output = input.replace(/(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(\d{4})/, "$3-$1-$2");
```

Actually, if the input format is guaranteed, you could just swap the pieces around based on their position without bothering to explicitly match digits and forward slashes:

```
var output = input.replace(/(..).(..).(....)/, "$3-$1-$2");
```

Comment: What about leap years? Daylight saving? Y2K? y***3***k? Oh, false alarm, no Date involved. Move on…

Comment: @RobG - It'll work for any date except your birthday.

Answer (score 11):

Use the [split](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjG-JCW3K_LAhWGew8KHYRWDqEQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fjsref_split.asp&usg=AFQjCNGzLD-MIahz1yk3hWzuWpITkgNDRw), [reverse](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjuzc6e3K_LAhWDZg8KHbSPAPAQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fjsref_reverse.asp&usg=AFQjCNF-knZ9vSi4fWIoQuh-GxUNE1nAxw) and [join](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi2kPuw3K_LAhVDLQ8KHX5_DPcQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjsref%2Fjsref_join.asp&usg=AFQjCNHuNvYc42F0HekLkUMOeBcvUuoqMg) functions:

```
var yourdate = date.split("/").reverse().join("-");
```

The split will split the date in various parts, with `/` as a delimiter.
The reverse function will reverse all the parts in the array, generated by the split. The join function will join all the parts back together, but now with `-` as a delimiter.

**Edit**

After reading the comments about the date being out of order: swap the second and third values of the array, created by the split function.

```
var dat = "03/07/2016"
var yourdate = dat.split("/").reverse();
var tmp = yourdate[2];
yourdate[2] = yourdate[1];
yourdate[1] = tmp;
yourdate = yourdate.join("-");
```

Comment: That will put the day and month in the wrong order. [Edit:] Sorry, this *does* work for the format specified in the question title, but the example in the question body is different. I don't know which the OP wants.

Comment: @Dries VB   this answer returns 2016-07-03. I need 2016-03-07.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to avoid using [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), manipulating strings, or loading an entire library like [moment](https://momentjs.com/), you can do this in one line by creating a new JavaScript `Date` object with the date you want formatted and calling its `toLocaleDateString` method with a compatible locale, such as `fr-CA`.

```
new Date('01/31/2020').toLocaleDateString('fr-CA') // "2020-01-31"
```

Supported in all modern browsers.

---

Credit: https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/date_format

Answer (score 1):

```
const date = new Date();
const convertedDate = date.toLocalDateString('en-IN').split('/').reverse().join('-');

console.log(convertedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below method. The trick is to use the unshift property.

```
function formatDate(__d){
    if(__d.indexOf('/')){
      var a = __d.split('/')
      var b = a.pop()
      a.unshift(b)
   }
  return a.join('-')
}
```