# Javascript convert string to date format yyyy-MM-dd

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, solr

I have a string which is in the format "05-01-2016" when i run the below code in chrome i get the correct output

> var fromDate = new Date(searchOpts.RunDateFrom);

```
        fromDate.format("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

output = "2016/05/01"

However, when this code is execute inside my js file i get this output

> Sun May 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

How do i prevent this? I need to pass the date in this format "2016-05-01" to solr

Comment: Short answer: JavaScript's date handling is horrid.  You have two options:  Search StackOver for one of the dozens of questions on the topic -or- use http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format JavaScript Date to yyyy-mm-dd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: @Jeremy I can't use external libs, any other way?

Comment: "Search StackOver for one of the dozens of questions on the topic" I linked to one already.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
formattedDate = fromDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (fromDate.getMonth()+1) + "-" + fromDate.getDate()
```

If you just need the string

Comment: You can append 0's to the month and the date if the string length is < 2

Comment: that's extacly what i was looking for, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
var year = fromDate.getFullYear();
var month = fromDate.getMonth() < 10 ? '0'+ fromDate.getMonth()+1 : fromDate.getMonth()+1

var date =  fromDate.getDate() < 10 ? '0'+ fromDate.getDate(): fromDate.getDate()
```