# JS / jQuery - Date format back to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, time, format

I'm getting the date format as `Tue May 31 2016 18:15:25 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)` but I need it in `2016-05-31`.

After several tries, on the last hour, I still can't get it right...

I need it to be as a filter for MySQL database.

How may I achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: @Turnip, thanks but that one is to get the name of the month (10-Aug-2016), mine is different.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: @William there are _many_ solutions in that thread that can be adapted for your format by simply switching the order of variables.

Comment: @DelightedD0D thank you! It worked perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Try this using JavaScript:

```
var year = date.getFullYear();
  var month = (1 + date.getMonth()).toString();
  month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;
  var day = date.getDate().toString();
  day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;
  var formattedDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
  alert(formattedDate);
  return formattedDate;
}

var date1 = new Date();
getFormattedDate(date1);
```

You can read more about JS date formats here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date. 
 You can also experiment on this plunk here : http://plnkr.co/edit/E7Nm5HlQu3pkYzIPSfVN

Answer (score -1):

Use the internationalization formatter

```
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('br').format(new Date(2016,4,31)) // => 2016-05-31
```

`br` indicates the Brazilian locale's formatting preferences, you can also use `en-us`, `en-gb`, etc. to both format *and* extract dates in a variety of different locales.

Comment: This doesnt address the actual value of Tue May 31 2016 18:15:25 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)