# How do you format a Date/Time in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've been having some trouble trying to get a `Date` object in TypeScript to format the way I want it to.

I have a class `Module` which is defined as:

```
export class Module {

    constructor(public id: number, public name: string, public description: string, 
                 public lastUpdated: Date, public owner: string) { }

    getNiceLastUpdatedTime(): String {

        let options: Intl.DateTimeFormatOptions = {
            day: "numeric", month: "numeric", year: "numeric",
            hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit"
        };

        return this.lastUpdated.toLocaleDateString("en-GB", options) + " " + this.lastUpdated.toLocaleTimeString("en-GB", options);
    }
}
```

When I call the method with the following code:

```
    let date = new Date(1478708162000); // 09/11/2016 16:16pm (GMT)
    let module = new Module(1, "Test", "description", date, "test owner");
    console.log(module.getNiceLastUpdatedTime());
```

I end up with the following printed in the console:

```
'9 November 2016 16:16:02 GMT'
```

What I want to see is:

```
09/11/2015 16:16
```

I've had a look at the documentation at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString  and I still can't see what I'm doing wrong (I know this is a JavaScript API documentation but I'm pretty sure that's what TypeScript is using under the hood).

Comment: The formatting of a Date is not something TypeScript has influence over, that's just javascript.

Comment: @Alex so even though the TypeScript `toLocale...` functions will accept a locale and an options object they're essentially useless?

Comment: There is no TypeScript function like that, that is a javascript function. TypeScript merely knows the api and provides a typed interface for it.

Comment: I get you now. Had a look at the transpiled code and it just passes it straight through untouched. It looks like the problem was with PhantomJS and the way it implements the Date API. It formats dates differently from the other browsers by the looks of it. Running it in Chrome gives me the output I expect.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

If you want the time out as well as the date you want `Date.toLocaleString()`.

This was direct from my console:

```
> new Date().toLocaleString()
> "11/10/2016, 11:49:36 AM"
```

You can then input locale strings and format string to get the precise output you want.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: The output from my console is the same. When I use the same code in TypeScript however, I get the same result as my original post.

Comment: It looks like the problem was with PhantomJS and the way it implements the Date API. It formats dates differently from the other browsers by the looks of it. Running it in Chrome gives me the output I expect.

Answer (score 62):

**Option 1:** Momentjs:

Install:

```
npm install moment --save
```

Import:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Usage:

```
let formattedDate = (moment(yourDate)).format('DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss')
```

**Option 2:** Use DatePipe if you are doing Angular:

Import:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
```

Usage:

```
const datepipe: DatePipe = new DatePipe('en-US')
let formattedDate = datepipe.transform(yourDate, 'dd-MMM-YYYY HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: Moment.js is a legacy project, now in maintenance mode. probably should use something else 

Comment: For Angular you should **NOT** use the DatePipe. Please checkout my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63902395/626639

Comment: For the second option, use "dd-.." instead of "DD"

Comment: The import statement should be `import moment from 'moment'`

Answer (score 48):

For **Angular** you should simply use `formatDate` instead of the `DatePipe`.

```
import {formatDate} from '@angular/common';

constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string) { 
    this.dateString = formatDate(Date.now(),'yyyy-MM-dd',this.locale);
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me, I didn't have to use any additional imports aside from what I was already using. formatDate has a good flexibility because you can pass in a date or a string or a number. Also if you don't want to inject LACALE_ID and use this.locale you can use a simple string like 'en_US'

Answer (score 36):

## Using the The Temporal API (2023)

A new js date api is in Stage 3 proposal (The Temporal API). Please take a look at that, you might be able to resolve most of your problems in a near future with it:

https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html

## Stop using momentjs - see alternatives below

As pointed by @jonhF in the comments, MomentJs recommends to not use MomentJs anymore.
Check https://momentjs.com/docs/

Instead, I'm keeping this list with my personal TOP 3 js date libraries for future reference.

- Date-fns - https://date-fns.org/
- DayJS - https://day.js.org/
- JS-Joda - https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/

## Old comment

### (Don't use momentjs lib anymore, it is deprecated!!!)

I suggest you to use [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/)

With moment you can have lot of outputs, and this one `09/11/2015 16:16` is one of them.

Comment: 2020 update: Moment is now suggesting to not use Moment. The short explanation is that native date formatting support has gotten better and if you still need more there are smaller and better libraries available. See their Docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: upvote for "stop using moment.js" :)

Answer (score 20):

In case you need it for angular, the simplest aproach with minimum code is:

```
import {formatDate} from '@angular/common';

formatDate(Date.now(),'yyyy-MM-dd','en-US');
```

Answer (score 17):

1. You can create pipe inherited from PipeTransform base
2. Then implement transform method

Used in Angular 4 - it's working. Best way to format a date is a pipe.

Create your custom pipe like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
    name: 'dateFormat'
  })
  export class DateFormatPipe extends DatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
       ///MMM/dd/yyyy 
       return super.transform(value, "MMM/dd/yyyy");
    }
  }
```

and it's used in a TypeScript class like this:

```
////my class////

export class MyComponent
{
  constructor(private _dateFormatPipe:DateFormatPipe)
  {
  }

  formatHereDate()
  {
     let myDate = this._dateFormatPipe.transform(new Date())//formatting current ///date here 
     //you can pass any date type variable 
  }
}
```

Comment: For Angular do not use the ``DatePipe`` in the typescript.
Instead, you can simply use ``formatDate`` instead as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63902395/626639.

Comment: @Seega Could you please explain why this should not be done this way?

Comment: Hi @KLiFF, it is not a dealbreaker but the purpose of a pipe is to be used in a template. So it is more a clean-code thing. Also using format date is making testing cleaner with the injection token.

Answer (score 13):

Here is another option for Angular (using own formatting function) - this one is for format:

YYYY-mm-dd hh:nn:ss

-you can adjust to your formats, just re-order the lines and change separators

```
dateAsYYYYMMDDHHNNSS(date): string {
  return date.getFullYear()
            + '-' + this.leftpad(date.getMonth() + 1, 2)
            + '-' + this.leftpad(date.getDate(), 2)
            + ' ' + this.leftpad(date.getHours(), 2)
            + ':' + this.leftpad(date.getMinutes(), 2)
            + ':' + this.leftpad(date.getSeconds(), 2);
}

leftpad(val, resultLength = 2, leftpadChar = '0'): string {
  return (String(leftpadChar).repeat(resultLength)
        + String(val)).slice(String(val).length);
}
```

For current time stamp use like this:

```
const curTime = this.dateAsYYYYMMDDHHNNSS(new Date());
console.log(curTime);
```

Will output e.g:  2018-12-31 23:00:01

Answer (score 5):

```
function _formatDatetime(date: Date, format: string) {
   const _padStart = (value: number): string => value.toString().padStart(2, '0');
return format
    .replace(/yyyy/g, _padStart(date.getFullYear()))
    .replace(/dd/g, _padStart(date.getDate()))
    .replace(/mm/g, _padStart(date.getMonth() + 1))
    .replace(/hh/g, _padStart(date.getHours()))
    .replace(/ii/g, _padStart(date.getMinutes()))
    .replace(/ss/g, _padStart(date.getSeconds()));
}
function isValidDate(d: Date): boolean {
    return !isNaN(d.getTime());
}
export function formatDate(date: any): string {
    var datetime = new Date(date);
    return isValidDate(datetime) ? _formatDatetime(datetime, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss') : '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more to add @kamalakar's answer, need to import the same in app.module and add DateFormatPipe to providers.

```
    import {DateFormatPipe} from './DateFormatPipe';
    @NgModule
    ({ declarations: [],  
        imports: [],
        providers: [DateFormatPipe]
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
function formatDate(date) { 
 return date.toISOString().replace('T', ' ').replaceAll('-', '/').substring(0, 19);
}

const currentdate = new Date();

console.log(formatDate(currentdate));
```

Answer (score 0):

1º Install:  `npm install moment --save`
2º Make Import : `import moment, { Moment } from 'moment'`
3º Coder:

```
var date = Date.now()
let formattedDate = (moment(date)).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me

```
    /**
     * Convert Date type to "YYYY/MM/DD" string 
     * - AKA ISO format?
     * - It's logical and sortable :)
     * - 20200227
     * @param Date eg. new Date()
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd 
     * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd?page=2&tab=active#tab-top
     */
    static DateToYYYYMMDD(Date: Date): string {
        let DS: string = Date.getFullYear()
            + '/' + ('0' + (Date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
            + '/' + ('0' + Date.getDate()).slice(-2)
        return DS
    }
```

You can certainly add HH:MM something like this...

```
    static DateToYYYYMMDD_HHMM(Date: Date): string {
        let DS: string = Date.getFullYear()
            + '/' + ('0' + (Date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
            + '/' + ('0' + Date.getDate()).slice(-2)
            + ' ' + ('0' + Date.getHours()).slice(-2)
            + ':' + ('0' + Date.getMinutes()).slice(-2)
        return DS
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

The best solution for me is the custom pipe from @Kamalakar but with a slight modification to allow passing the format:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
    name: 'dateFormat'
  })
  export class DateFormatPipe extends DatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, format: any): any {
       return super.transform(value, format);
    }
  }
```

And then called as:

```
console.log('Formatted date:', this._dateFormatPipe.transform(new Date(), 'MMM/dd/yyyy'));
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is an Example of a simple date format function

```
formatDate(value, format, offset){
 format = format || 'yyyy-MM-dd';
 offset = offset || '+0300';

if(!(value instanceof Date)){
   value = new Date(value);
   if(value === null || value === undefined) {
      throw new Error(
      'DateFormatException: value passed' + 'is not a valid date'
      );
    }
  }
  return value; // TODO implement this return $filter('date')(value, format, offset);
}
```

Comment: your function is missing a meaningful body

Comment: looks not clean bro, hard to read my gangsta