# How can I display specific parts in console.log(...)or print differently in html?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I want to display current time, date and date using typescript and HTML

The code I am using for javascript and HTML to print is:

const time1 = new Date();
console.log(time1.toLocaleString())

{{time1}}//in HTML

The output I get:
Sun Nov 27 2022 20:26:33 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

The output I want:
Sun Nov 27 2022 20:26

I don't not want seconds or time zone

Comment: Note that `.toLocaleString()` looks different based on implementation. In my brower it returns `11/27/2022, 5:42:02 PM`. For your date format you could use a replace to get rid of the trailing content: `console.log(time1.toLocaleString().replace(/:\d\d GMT.*/, ''));`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you format a Date/Time in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526102/how-do-you-format-a-date-time-in-typescript)