# Result in JavaScript Method

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I have the following switch statement function which is returning entries in an API from a set time date:

```
entries: {
        recent: function(callback) {
            return self.request(rest.get, '/timeentries', { startDate: '2016-02-15' }, function(result) {
                callback(result);
            });
        },
```

This is working fine, I am getting results back from anything post 2016-02-15.

However, I don't want this to be static. I want to be able to pull a date range from when this is run.

I have the following code which returns the current week:

```
var curr = new Date; // get current date
var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); 
var firstDay = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toUTCString();
```

**firstDay** returns the start of the week, which is what I want to put in place of **startDate: '2016-02-15'**.

Question, how would I put firstDay in here, the following wont work:

```
entries: {
        recent: function(callback) {
          var curr = new Date; // get current date
          var first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay(); 
          var firstDay = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toUTCString();
            return self.request(rest.get, '/timeentries', { firstDate }, function(result) {
                callback(result);
            });
        },
```

Comment: where is the switch statement?

Comment: `{ firstDate }` is not a proper object

Comment: @epascarello it is valid in ES6, as a shorthand object initialization

Comment: This looks like a simple typo, firstDay vs firstDate.

Comment: Looking at your historial, you only accepted one answer within all your questions. You should catch up and start accepting good answers to show your gratitude for the effort the people put into helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely the first call and compare it to your second call, your object is bad formed. They have to be a `key: value` pair having `startDate` as the key and the date as the value, so:

```
return self.request(rest.get, '/timeentries', { startDate: firstDate }, function(result) {
    callback(result);
});
```

In the new ES6 specs `{ firstDate }` is a valid object that will put `firstDate` as the key, BUT you need `startDate` as the key instead.

Also, you don't have any variable `firstDate` anywhere but a `firstDay` one, hence the object will be `{ startDate: firstDay }` for it to work.

Also, `toUTCString` returns an entire date string, like this: `Sun, 12 Feb 2017 02:01:35 GMT` and you need only the `YYY-MM-DD` format so looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23593099/1525495) you will need to do:

```
var d = new Date(),
    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
    day = '' + d.getDate(),
    year = d.getFullYear();

if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

var firstDay = [year, month, day].join('-');
```

Comment: That's only true if he's not using ES6

Comment: Nope. The thing is that the key name is `startDate`, not `firstDate`. Going to edit to clarify it...

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález

Thank you! Yes, I am using ES6, and the firstDate / FirstDay was a type when posting on here.

Thank you, this solved my issue! - Should have thought about the format!