# How to get date in format yyyy-mm-dd in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have date in format: `Thu, 01 Dec 2016 00:00:00 GMT`, how to get date of format `yyyy-mm-dd` from that?

Comment: Really, have you tried anything??

Comment: if you are ok with libraries, you can use moment.js for this

Comment: @Durga I don't even know HOW to parse that, so I just ask question. I try to find solution, but didn't find that. Is that problem to ask question, when u can`t find solution?

Comment: duplicate post of this so post ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: @Klimenkomud if you search first link only will give you an answer. If you want you can use moment.js instead. `moment('Thu, 01 Dec 2016 00:00:00 GMT').format("YYYY-MM-DD");`

Comment: For you to know: I just used google with "format date javascript" (that is your issue) and I got plenty of results like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date). You can ask questions here **showing first your effort to try to solve the issue**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to plain JS:

```
Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
  var mm = this.getMonth() + 1;
  var dd = this.getDate();

  return [this.getFullYear(),
          (mm>9 ? '' : '0') + mm,
          (dd>9 ? '' : '0') + dd
         ].join('-');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want split it

```js
var a = 'Thu, 01 Dec 2016 00:00:00 GMT'
var s = a.split(' ')
console.log(s)
console.log(s[3]+'-'+s[2]+'-'+s[0])
```