# How to reset a date in Firefox input[type=date]?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-input

Firefox v57.0.1 supports the attribute "date" for the HTML input tag.
I would like in jQuery to reset the date value when the user click on a radio button like this:
[image]

In order to get this result:

[image]

My jQuery code:

```
$("input[name=f_foo_duration]").click(function() {
        
   if ($("#f_foo_duration_until").is(':checked')) {
       $("#f_foo_duration_date").attr("readonly", false);
   }else{
      $("#f_foo_duration_date").attr("readonly", true);
      $("#f_foo_duration_date").attr( "value", new Date() ); <-- here
   }
});
```

I tested:

- val("")
- val(null)
- val("0000-00-00")
- val( new Date() )

without any success... is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set an input element's value use the jQuery function `elem.val("...")`:

```js
$(function() {
  $('[name="contact"]:radio').on("change", function() {
    if ($("#f_foo_duration_until").is(":checked")) {
      let now = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
      $("#f_foo_duration_date").val(now);      
      $("#f_foo_duration_date").attr("readonly", false);
    } else {
      $("#f_foo_duration_date").val("YYYY-MM-DD");
      $("#f_foo_duration_date").attr("readonly", true);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#my-form > * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my-form">

  <input type="radio" id="f_foo_duration_until" name="contact" value="email">
  <label for="f_foo_duration_until">Valid until</label>

  <input id="f_foo_duration_date" name="f_foo_duration" type="date" value="2017-06-01">
  </input>

  <input type="radio" id="f_foo_duration_unlimited" name="contact" value="unlimited">
  <label for="f_foo_duration_unlimited">Unlimited</label>

</form>
```

Comment: One important thing : use *.val("YYYY-MM-DD")* before set *.attr("readonly", true)*. I lost time because of that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ready to clear or reset using jQuery, try this code:

```
$("input[type=date]").val("");
```

Comment: This just seems to repeat the accepted answer from 2017.

Answer (score 0):

We'll need to get it to the YYYY-MM-DD format.

```
  $("#f_foo_duration_date").val(new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10));
```

See this question for more info on switching the format: [Format JavaScript Date to yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reaching this post for a slightly different issue :

For chrome it works fine with `val("")`

Not for Firefox because of the `readonly` attribute (why?)

If you remove 'readonly', `val("")` and variations works fine on firefox.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.