# Jquery Date Format Conversion

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web-applications

Want to convert the date format which is like 16-Mar-2016 to 2016-03-16 in  jquery

```
var requestStartDate = new Date(Date.parse(16-Mar-2016)).format("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

I tried with the above code, it is not working.

Comment: $("#testDate").val($.datepicker.formatDate('yyyy-MM-dd', requestDate));
if using jquery UI

Comment: Why do you need to do it in jQuery and not just in vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: You should take a look at the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd/29774197
and then use `formatDate(Date.parse("16-Mar-2016"))`

Comment: is it possible to store the converted date format in variable, the above code is like binding the converted value in input field.

Comment: @SMugunthankumar Directly call the function and store it in a variable


var y = formatDate("2016-03-16");
alert(y);