# converting date from a given format to yyyy-mm-dd in momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have the date in this format.I am using format() of monentjs.
Currently mydate is in this format 2018-10-11T16:31:27+05:30

```
let newdate=let newdate=this.state.startDate.format();
```

I want to get this date in this format 2018-10-22.
I tried using this

```
let formatfun=(date)=>{
      let x=moment(date,"moment.HTML5_FMT.DATE");
      return x;
    }
```

but could not reach there .

Answer (score 0):

```js
const newdate = "2018-10-11T16:31:27+05:30"; // this.state.startDate.format();
const formatfun = date => {
    return date.substr(0, 10);
}
console.log(formatfun(newdate));
```

Would this help? Just taking the first 10 chars of your date string.

Or if it is of date type, look over at [Format JavaScript Date to yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd) (possible duplicate).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
let formatfun=(date)=>{
  let x=moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can learn more about [formatting with moment.js here.](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

```js
let formatfun = (date) => {
   let x = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
   return x;
}

let date = '2018-10-22T16:31:27+05:30';
console.log(date);
console.log(formatfun(date));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

> moment("yourdate","dateformat").format("newformat");

```
let formatfun=(date)=>{
      let x=moment(date,"moment.HTML5_FMT.DATE").format('yyyy-dd-mm');
      return x;
}
```

read more here : https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment(newdate).format("YYYY-MM-DD")

check following url for more reference :-

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/