# how to get difference date using javascript more specific

Tags: javascript, date-format, date-difference

hello guys i would like to get difference date using javascript, in php Im using this script to get difference date :

```
 $tgl1 = date('Y-m-d');  
 $tgl2 = '2019-12-31';

 $pecah1 = explode("-", $tgl1);
 $date1 = $pecah1[2];
 $month1 = $pecah1[1];
 $year1 = $pecah1[0];
 $pecah2 = explode("-", $tgl2);
 $date2 = $pecah2[2];
 $month2 = $pecah2[1];
 $year2 =  $pecah2[0];

 $jd1 = GregorianToJD($month1, $date1, $year1);
 $jd2 = GregorianToJD($month2, $date2, $year2);
 $selisih = $jd2 - $jd1;
```

and how to do in javascript

Comment: @priyanshi srivastava, how if format date 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Comment: your link is wrong, if first_date more than second_date the result should minus(-) day , but  it keep no minus(-)

Comment: My bad..i'd taken down my flag and have answered below check it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help :)

```js
date1 = "2018-12-25"; //date1
date2 = "2019-01-01"; //date2

var one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

var x = date1.split("-");
var y = date2.split("-");

var new_date1 = new Date(x[0], (x[1] - 1), x[2]);
var new_date2 = new Date(y[0], (y[1] - 1), y[2]);

var month1 = x[1] - 1;
var month2 = y[1] - 1;

_Diff = Math.ceil((new_date2.getTime() - new_date1.getTime()) / (one_day));

console.log(_Diff);
```

Comment: how to get date today format 'yyyy-mm-dd' in javascript ?

Comment: @GustiErlangga https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd