# How to convert string to type date in dynamically generated mat-table

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a mat-table which displays columns Date, Before Time Period and After Time Period.
Code for HTML :-

```
<ng-container
            matColumnDef="{{ column }}"
            *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay"
        >
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{ column }}</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                {{ element[column]  }}
            </td>
        </ng-container>
```

TypeScript Code:

```
columnsToDisplay = [
    'executionDate',
    'previousTimePeriod',
    'afterTimePeriod'
];
executionDate: string = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
```

If I use a pipe `{{ element[column]  | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}` to display Date of type string to date type then I am not able to see Before and After Time Period.
How can I view date only as 'yyyy-MM-dd'

Comment: Please provide some sample data to work with. Also, it would be really helpful if you could provide a sample stackblitz replicating your issue.

Answer (score 4):

create a pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({
  name: 'momentPipe',
  pure: false
})
export class MomentPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor() { }

  transform(value: string, dateFormat: string): any {
        return moment(value).format(dateFormat);
    }
}
```

then in html:

```
<span >{{ element[column] | momentPipe: 'dddd D MMM YYYY' }}</span>
```

You need [moment](http://momentjs.com/) for this approach
see [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) more formats

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use [angular momentjs](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment)

So it'll be simple that you can use its filter as

```
{{ element[column] | amParse: 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSZ' | amDateFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}
```

Comment: I tried using amParse but now in place of date I get Invalid date

Comment: what is the real value of element[column]? can you log it?

Comment: {
  "executionId" : "dsjjks2328",
  "label" : null,
  "jobId" : "ew7348",
  "executionDate" : "2016-08-28T18:30:00.000+0000",
  "previousTimePeriod" : "2016-14",
  "afterTimePeriod" : "2016-15",
  "status" : "RUNNING",
  "project" : {
    "id" : 18
  }

Comment: Can you try {{ element[column] | amParse: 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSZ' | amDateFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}

Comment: Tried `{{ element[column] | amParse: 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSZ' | amDateFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}` Its not working

Comment: This is the date that I want to format "executionDate" : "2016-08-28T18:30:00.000+0000"

Comment: what does it show with {{ element[column] | amParse: 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSSZ' | amDateFormat: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}

Answer (score 0):

> Another idea is you can convert your string-date into 'yyyy-MM-dd'
>   format and replace with replacing with string-date.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd) should help you.