# Unable to display date in <ion-datetime> component

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am building the ionic app(v-4),I am unable to display the `date` from the `api`. My `JSON` looks like this:

```
{
user_name: "Jhon"
status: "Open"
meeting_date: "31-08-2019"
remark: "No remarks"
request_id: 958
}
```

I have tried to display the `date` in `<ion-datetime>` as shown below:

**HTML**

```
  <form [formGroup]="editForm">
     <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="stacked">Date</ion-label>
            <ion-datetime formControlName="meeting_date" [(ngModel)]="resObj.meetingDate"></ion-datetime>
      </ion-item>
 </form>
```

**TS**

```
public resObj;
ngOnInit() {
    this.resObj = this.navParams.data.paramRequest;
    this.updateForm = this.fb.group({
      remark : [null],
      .
      .
      meeting_date: [null],
    });
  }
```

> I got this error:  **Error parsing date: "undefined". Please provide a valid ISO 8601 datetime format: https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime**

So i tried this solution ===> **[ionic 2 ion-datetime ISO Format issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361108/ionic-2-ion-datetime-iso-format-issue/47843362#47843362)**

i,e Using ISO format before displaying the `date` in the template like this:

**HTML**

```
  <form [formGroup]="editForm">
     <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="stacked">Date</ion-label>
            <ion-datetime formControlName="meeting_date" [(ngModel)]="meetingDate "></ion-datetime>
      </ion-item>
 </form>
```

**TS**

```
public resObj;
ngOnInit() {
    this.resObj = this.navParams.data.paramRequest;
    const meetingDate =  this.resObj.meeting_date.toISOString(); <======
    this.updateForm = this.fb.group({
      remark : [null],
      .
      .
      meeting_date: [null],
    });
  }
```

Still i was unable to show `date` in `ion-datetime`

I am unable find what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I sugest to use [moment](https://momentjs.com/) and then you could even create a pipe like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54645041/how-to-convert-string-to-type-date-in-dynamically-generated-mat-table/54645488#54645488). You could use it like this:

```
<span >{{ resObj.meetingDate | momentPipe: 'dddd D MMM YYYY' }}</span>
```

other formats [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/).

UPDATE:
create o form

```
public someForm: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initSomeForm();
  }
  initSomeForm() {
    this.someForm = new FormGroup({
      userName: new FormControl(this.resObj.user_name, [Validators.required]),
      meetingDate: new FormControl(this.resObj.meeting_date, [Validators.required]),
      status: new FormControl(this.resObj.status, [Validators.required]),
      remark: new FormControl(this.resObj.remark),
      requestId: new FormControl(this.resObj.request_id),
    });
  }
```

in html

```
  <form [formGroup]="someForm">
<ion-item>
       <ion-label position="stacked">Date</ion-label>
       <ion-datetime formControlName="meetingDate" displayFormat="MM DD YY"></ion-datetime>
 </ion-item>
```

Comment: Without using `moment.js` and `pipes` is it possible to do?

Comment: Please read my edited question, I want to display the date in `<ion-datetime>` component not in any `tags`.

Comment: I am able add the `date` from `<ion-datetime>`, But couldn't able to bind, Since i need 2 way data binding to update the `JSON object`.

Comment: you are binding the <ion-datetime> to a const, not to a JSON object, remove ngModel, bind formControl to JSON object property

Comment: i updated the answer, i use reactiveForms, https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: I have already tried this approach (reactive-forms), Still  throwing this warning: **Error parsing date: "undefined". Please provide a valid ISO 8601 datetime format**

Comment: try to console.log(this.navParams.data.paramRequest);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198488/discussion-between-shankar-and-radu-tataru).

Comment: Log result ===> `bell_count: 0 
user_name: "Jhon" 
m_status: "Open" 
meeting_date: "31-08-2019" 
provider_action: false 
remark: "No remarks" 
request_id: 958 
service_name: "Service 1"`