# Javascript Convert January 01,1970 to 1970-01-01

Tags: javascript

can someone help me solve this problem. In my textfield I have a value of January 01,1970 and I want it to change to 1970-01-01(year-month-day). How to do it in javascript?

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Read about `momentjs`, `new Date('January 01,1970')` `<-` Not reliable!

Comment: @CodeManiac I have tried toLocaleString  but I got 'not a function' error on my console.

Comment: Go over there, it's already resolved : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format JavaScript Date to yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**momentJS**](https://momentjs.com/)

```js
let date = `January 01,1970 `
console.log( moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have moment.js and I never know that it can help me until you answered my inquiry. Thanks