# conversion of DD-MON-YY to YYYY-MM-DD in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, date-formatting

I have a requirement where i need to convert the date format from

`DD-MON-YY to YYYY-MM-DD` in javascript.

I have used the function below

```
function SimpleDate(inputdate) {
    var outputdate = new Date(inputdate);
    console.log(outputdate);
    var Outputyear=outputdate.toDateString().substr(outputdate.toDateString().lastIndexOf(' ')+1,4);
    console.log(Outputyear);
    return Outputyear ;

}

SimpleDate('05-FEB-19')
```

can anyone help here.

When i am passing the date as below . I am getting `SimpleDate('05/02/19')`

i am getting `1919` as response.

Comment: What `MON` prints?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown for the MON i am using the map and based on the month value i am assign the value.

Comment: @saylestyler No it is not duplicate. Here the input format is DD-MON-YY.

Comment: According to your sample data, the input is actually DD/MM/YY . Please clarify and [edit] your question

Comment: If you can use an external library, I would recommend [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/), it will make manipulating dates with JS much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do some string manipulation:

```
 "20" + input.split("/").reverse().join("-")
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be something like:

```
let formattedTime = new Date( //2. Creates new date from string
   `05-FEB-19`.replace(/-/g, ` `) //1. replaces all '-' with space
).toLocaleString(`zu-ZA`); 

/* 3. Returns a string formated to a traditional South African formatting (
South African just because they use exactly the format that you described). */

console.log(formattedTime)// -> "2019-02-05 00:00:00"
```

What is cool in this approach is that .toLocaleString() can format date in whatever format you prefer.

In case you pass no argument to that, it formats time according to the format that the final user prefers.

For instance:

```
 new Date().toLocaleString(); //-> "١٩‏/٣‏/٢٠١٩ ٨:٢٧:٥٨ م" if your OS language is Arabic.

 new Date().toLocaleString(); //-> "19/3/2019 00:00:06" if your OS language is Spanish.

 new Date().toLocaleString(); //-> "19.3.2019, 00:00:06" if your OS language is German.
```