# Why can't I get the length of dateobject.getMonth()?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I followed the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd) question.

Here's my code:

```
    edate = new Date()
    edate.setYear(edate.getFullYear() + 1);
    month = edate.getMonth();
    console.log(month);
    console.log(month.length);
```

This returns:

```
3
undefined
```

Comment: Be careful re setYear: "[This feature is no longer recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setYear). Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it"

Comment: `setFullYear`: read the link in the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you listed from the other question, the value stored in `month` was converted to a `String`. This can be done like this (concatenation with empty `String` causes `toString()` conversion):

```
month = '' + edate.getMonth();
```

A `Number` value does not have a `length` property, but a `String` does. This is what the original code was utilizing.

#### Update

A more clear approach (as mentioned) would be to utilize the `String` constructor that accepts a `Number` as input and converts it to a `String`, like so:

```
month = String(edate.getMonth());
```

Or, you could call `toString()` directly on you the value that is returned from `getMonth()`, like so:

```
month = edate.getMonth().toString();
```

Comment: add this to your answer `String(edate.getMonth())`. It can also be use to coerce a number into a string