# I want to change the date format to "yyyy-mm-dd"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

In my script tag, `var today` shows in the `Sat Sep 07 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` date format, and I want to change this date format to the `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

My code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var date  = new Date();
        var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
        console.log(today);
    });
</script>
```

I am trying like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var date  = new Date();
        var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
        var newDate = "<?php echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime(today)); ?>";
        console.log(newDate);
    });
</script>
```

How can I change date format using `strtotime()`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: You should probably have a look at the difference between code that is run on the server (like PHP) and on the client (like JavaScript) and how they can interact with each other (hint: not like you think)

Comment: Why are you passing a javascript variable to PHP?

Comment: @Andrea Manzi: There is for 110% sure a duplicate somewhere, but isn't that one about parsing a string, rather than just formatting (misleading title)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes, but the accepted answer uses the `Date` object to format the value. Using that exact code (but skipping `var d = new Date(date)` to parse the string since OP here already has `today` as a Date object and can just use `today` where the original code uses `d`) will provide the expected result.

Comment: As for *"How can I change date format using `strtotime()`?"* -- you don't. `today` is a Javascript variable, PHP has no access to it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With PHP  get date of today and change format

```
$origDate = "2019-01-15";

$newDate = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($origDate));
echo $newDate;
```

Output

```
01-15-2019
```

With js

```
  var date  = new Date();
  var year=date.getFullYear();
  var month= date.getMonth();
  var date=date.getDay();

 console.log(` ${day}:${month}:${year}`);
```

Comment: In JS `date.getMonth()` will return month starting from 0, so you need to add 1. Also, `-`getDay` will return the day of the week.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var date  = new Date();
        var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
        var newDate = "<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>";
        console.log(newDate);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If you're setting `newDate` with PHP then `date` and `today` are completely redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use server-side logic when you already have everything to get the desired formatting:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        let today = new Date();
        let strToday = today.getFullYear() + "-" + today.getMonth() + "-" + today.getDay();
        console.log(strToday);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply format the date. Don't forget that getMonth() is zero-based.

```js
const date = new Date();

const mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
const dd = date.getDate();

const format = [
  date.getFullYear(),
  (mm > 9 ? '' : '0') + mm,
  (dd > 9 ? '' : '0') + dd
].join('-');

console.log(format);
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a function to change the date format in “yyyy-mm-dd”.

Demo on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ecv7waru/

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var date  = new Date();
        var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
        var newDate = formatDate(today);
        console.log(newDate);
    });

    function formatDate(date) {
        var d = new Date(date),
                month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
                day = '' + d.getDate(),
                year = d.getFullYear();

        if (month.length < 2)
            month = '0' + month;
        if (day.length < 2)
            day = '0' + day;

        return [year, month, day].join('-');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

the Best with fewer line of code can be done by using `moment` as follows in `ONE LINE`

```js
 var today =moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
 console.log(today)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```