# How do I select the date from the date picker widget using cypress

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I am doing the testing of my web application using cypress.
In the application I have to automate the test case for changing the date using the date picker calendar.
Can anyone tell please me how do I select the date from the date picker calendar ,( I do not want to directly input the date in the input field as the input filed is read only and its value can be only changed using the date picker calendar widget).

Comment: it would help if you can provide the code of the date picker? Because you need to do a few steps: 1. Open de date picker. 2. Select the correct year/month. 3. Select the correct day. And some extra info is needed, what year/month/day do you want to select? is the 'today' fine, or should it be something else?

Comment: Today date is fine,So basically in the calandar wiget , there is two dropdown ,one is to select month and second one is to select year,below there is a table like structure in which all the dates are displayed.

Comment: Can you inspect the select month and select year as other web elements? If so there is no difference from other web elements handling.

Comment: @ankitkansal there's no difference you picking the date or inserting it to the field.

 cy.get('[formcontrolname="startDate"]').then(($startDate) => {
            cy.wrap($startDate).type('04/04/2022')
        });

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 2):

You can inspect the web elements on the date picker. 
If you can show more html source code it would be great.

Basically on a jquery date picker you can do the example like this,

```
    //click the date picker
    cy.get('#datepicker').click();
    //choose previous month
    cy.contains('Prev').click();
    //choose next month 
    cy.contains('Next').click();
    //choose date 24
    cy.contains('24').click();
```

Comment: This won't work if the number of the date is elsewhere on the page, which was the case for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can Look into this code . It Would be help You.

```
cy.get('input[name="Date"]').invoke('val').then((text) => {
    expect('08/05/2019').to.equal(text);
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got a Cypress test to select a datepicker value in a Vue web app.

Set a date, for example today (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29774197/9443322):

```
    let d = new Date();
    const offset = d.getTimezoneOffset();
    d = new Date(d.getTime() - (offset*60*1000));
    let myDate = d.toISOString().split('T')[0];
```

Then tell Cypress to click on the datepicker and force click the relevant data-date:

```
    cy.get('[data-cy=my-datepicker]').click().get('[data-date='+myDate+']', { force: true }).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

at my current company we work with react, so here is how I did it:

```
selectDate(day: number){
    cy.get(`.react-datepicker__input-container > input`).click()
    cy.wait(1000)
    cy.get(`.react-datepicker__day--0${day}`).click()
    return this
  }
```

1. click on a date field to open date picker
2. added wait for 1 sec which is not mandatory
3. select desired date

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

cy.get('#date').type('2020-10-20');

cy.get('#date') - access the datepicker element; i used an 'id' named '#date'
.type('2020-10-20') - cypress will select and enter this date using 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easier sloution to pick a date in cypress by datepicker:

```
cy.get('#staffdob')
.click()
.type('07211994');
cy.get(':nth-child(3) > .panel-body')
.click();
```

I clicked on date picker using its ID and I typed a date in the date picker field.
Then I clicked on the the form (modal body) to close the date picker

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. It will ***automatically Select the current Date***:

```
 //First it Clicks on the calendar's field.
cy.get('#date').click();
//Then Clicks on current date. 
cy.get('.ui-datepicker-days-cell-over > .ui-state-default').click();
```

**Remember** that this class`.ui-datepicker-days-cell-over` may be different in your case but next is always same.