# v-calendar plugin date formatting

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, date-formatting, vcalendar

I'm using v-calendar plugin in Nuxt project.
Everything works and here is my code:

```js
<script>
export default {
 data() {
  return {
   ArrivalDate: new Date(),
   DepartureDate: new Date(),
  }
 },
 methods: {
  Submit() {
   console.log(this.ArrivalDate)
  },
 },
}
</script>
```

```html
<h3>Arrival <</h3>
<v-date-picker v-model="ArrivalDate" :min-date="new Date()" ></v-date-picker>
    

     
<h3>Departure </h3>
<v-date-picker v-model="DepartureDate" :min-date="ArrivalDate"></v-date-picker>
```

I'm looking to the [docs](https://vcalendar.io/guide/#formatting-parsing-dates) but don't know how to format and display this data. I only get errors.
this is my output now:

**Tue Nov 19 2019 22:15:01 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)**

I want to format it like **DD:MM:YY** and nothing else.

Comment: So as I understood, do you want to get `DD:MM:YY` format string from `Date` value?

Comment: Yes. Currently my date is displayed too long. I want to be DD:MM:YY

Comment: It seems you are looking for this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052

Comment: Check this - https://codesandbox.io/s/date-picker-parse-format-4nx9r?file=/src/App.vue