# date.getFullYear is not a function inside while()

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I run this in node.js v11.6.0

```
const now = new Date(Date.now());
let date = now;
date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() - 1);
let str = date.getFullYear() + "-" + date.getMonth() + "-" + date.getDate();
while(!data[str]){
    date = date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
    str = date.getFullYear() + "-" + date.getMonth() + "-" + date.getDate();
}
```

And get:

```
trail.js:15 str = date.getFullYear() + "-" + date.getMonth() + "-" + date.getDate();
TypeError: date.getFullYear is not a function
```

inside the while loop date.setDate() works but date.getFullYear() is not a function all of a sudden.

Comment: Always worth [checking the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate)...

Comment: `new Date(Date.now())` will produce an identical result to `new Date()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);` you're assigning the return value of `setDate` which is an integer to `date`. That's why you can't call `.getFullYear` later, since numbers don't have that method.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate):

> **Return Value**
>
> The number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the
>   given date (the Date object is also changed in place).

```
while(!data[str]){
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
    str = date.getFullYear() + "-" + date.getMonth() + "-" + date.getDate();
}
```

Have in mind that `date.getMonth()` returns an integer number, between 0 and 11. If you want to format it correctly you can check:

[Format JavaScript date as yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: OH RIGHT i need to just call the setter and get rid of the assignment. LOL.

Comment: But the month number will still be wrong, and not padded to two digits (nor will the date). :-(

Comment: @RobG I focused on the problem he mentioned, that's why I missed it. Edited my answer to tackle that.