# Better way to get the current date for the input type "date" as a default value?

Tags: javascript

I've come up with using a function on page load:

```
function getDate() {
    let currentDate = new Date();
    let year = currentDate.getFullYear();
    let month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
    if (month < 10) {
        month = "0" + month
    }
    let day = currentDate.getDate();
    let today = year + '-' + month + '-' + day
    return today
}
```

Once the page loads, the return value is inserted into the  value parameter. The function just looks really messy, is there a more concise way to do this?

Comment: You can use moment.js

Comment: if you use moment  check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: See the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29774197/5648954) of the link above for a "simpler" solution (and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd/29774197#comment84587622_29774197) comment if you're experiencing issues)

Comment: @ShubhamNagota Not every date-related question should be answered with "use moment.js". This question most certainly does not need moment.js at all.