# How to call Java function dynamically from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I started to learn JSP, so I want to make displaying time dynamic on JSP.

I created a class Times

```java
public class Times {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf =null;
    LocalDateTime now =null;
    public Times()
    {
         dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");  
    }
    public String getTime()
    {
         now = LocalDateTime.now(); 

        return dtf.format(now);
    }


}
```

I call `getTime` function in the JSP file

```html
<%@ page import="data.Times"%>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var time="";
    function showTime(){
        <%
            Times t=new Times();
        %>
           time = '<%=t.getTime()%>';
    }
    function startTime() {
        showTime();
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML =time;
        t = setInterval(function () {
            startTime()
        }, 500);
        }
</script>
<style>
    @font-face{
        font-family: clock;
        src:url(content/digital-7.ttf)
    }
    #time{
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: clock;
        font-size: 100px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startTime()">
    <div id="time" align="center">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But the problem is that the page is loaded, however, time is initialized but it remains unchanged.

If I refresh the page, time is properly changed.
Can I change time dynamic way ?

Comment: http://34.91.166.167/  -- This page is my working page on googleCloud

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you display that page, the JSP is executed *once* on the server, which means that `t.getTime()` is executed *once*.

If you do a "View Source" in the web browser, you'll see that the server has generated the following:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

    var time="";
    function showTime(){
           time = '2020/03/03 17:47:45';
    }
    function startTime() {
        showTime();
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML =time;
        t = setInterval(function () {
            startTime()
        }, 500);
        }
</script>
```

As you can see, the value of `time` is now fixed at the date/time the server processed the JSP. Calling `showTime()` repeatedly will not change the value of `time`.

If you want the time value to be "live", you need to do this in JavaScript code, not JSP code.

Here is a way to do it, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50130338/5221149) to question "[Format JavaScript date as yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23593052/5221149)":

```javascript
    function showTime() {
        const date = Date.now();
        time = new Date(date.getTime() - date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)
                .toISOString()       // yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ
                .replace(/\..*/, '') // yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss
                .replace(/T/, ' ')   // yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
                .replace(/-/g, '/'); // yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss
    }
```

Comment: Thanks  for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have two main options:

## AJAX

[AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) can be used in order to send a request to your backend. On your backend you could respond to these AJAX requests with the time and then in the callback refresh the time value.

## Doing only on the client-side

You can also create a Date object based on the time received from the server and adjust it. But I suppose that you are more interested in the AJAX solution

## Further explanation

Your code currently sends a page to the browser `where` the time is properly calculated initially. Your `setInterval` calls showTime, but `<%=t.getTime()%>` was evaluated at the server before the page was sent out. You need to establish further communication with your server if you intend to get information from there. Via AJAX, for example.

Comment: @CengizAltürk you are welcome. Also, I'm happy that your issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

time remains unchanged unless page invoked. in order to call dynamically try to refresh it for specified interval like below , include it in `<head> </head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >
```

Comment: Thanks  for your answer

Comment: It's a pleasure  Cengiz Altürk