# JavaScript, wrong yyyy-mm-dd of today

Tags: javascript

I need to get the yyyy-mm-dd of today on `const today2`. I'm trying this:

```
const today = new Date();
console.log('today', today)
// today Wed Mar 11 2020 23:13:35 GMT-0300 (hora de verano de Chile)
const today2 = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
console.log('today2', today2)
// today2 2020-03-12
```

I need to get `2020-03-11` but I'm getting `2020-03-12`
why? I don't want to use `moment`

Comment: Seems like a timezone issue - by removing the GMT-0300 what you are doing is getting the date of now +3hours - which is giving the next date since the time is 11pm. - or in effect you are getting Wed Mar 12 2020 02:13:35

Comment: `23:13:35 GMT-0300` is `02:13:35` on the next day - you're using ISO string, therefore GMT, therefore the value is correct

Comment: Check Local TimeZone in your computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const today = new Date();
const today2 = new Date(today.getTime()  - (today.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString().slice(0,10);
```

Using **toISOString()** converts the timezone to UTC(standard time)

Answer (score 1):

> Try this function..

```
    export const getTodayDate = () => {
            var today = new Date();
            var dd = (today.getDate()).toString();
            var mm = (today.getMonth() + 1).toString(); 
            var yyyy = (today.getFullYear()).toString();

            if (parseInt(dd) < 10) {
                dd = '0' + dd;
            } 

            if (parseInt(mm) < 10) {
                mm = '0' + mm;
            } 

            return yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
     }

const today2 = getTodayDate();
console.log(today2);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found a better solution, I'll post as an answer. I'll give you +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I got it from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50130338/3541320

```
const today = new Date();
const todayYYYMMDD = new Date(today.getTime() - (today.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000 ))
  .toISOString()
  .split("T")[0];
```