# React Native Date Picker Not Letting Me Choose A Date

Tags: react-native, datepicker

I have implemented a react-native-datepicker, and it is displaying correctly and the default date is correct as the initial state is:

```
date: new Date()
```

However, when I press the icon to choose a date, all the dates are greyed out, and you can scroll but when you let go it just goes back and won't let you choose a date.

Any idea why I am having this problem?

```js
<DatePicker
  style={{width: 200}}
  mode="date"
  date={this.state.date}
  format="DD-MM-YYYY"
  minDate={this.state.date}
  maxDate="01-01-2030"
  confirmBtnText="Confirm"
  cancelBtnText="Cancel"
  onDateChange={(d) => {this.setState({date: d})}}
/>
```

Comment: in OnDateChange try to remove the curly brackets around {this.setState} so its start like this (d) => this.setState .. . . .

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work...

Comment: mh maybe the format is wrong try to format the date with moment.js format function or check the format of this.state.date and if it is like maxDate.

Comment: have you got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `new Date()` isn't in the format you want. `new Date()` infact returns an *Object*. It is hard to convert this object to the required format, but here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd) to a solution on Stack Overflow, just in case.

I recommend using libraries like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) because it's easy to format dates using it and you can do a lot more.

In your case, I suggest replacing the initial state value to:

`{date: moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY')}`

Beware! Setting `minDate={this.state.date}` will restrict you from selecting older dates, i.e once you select a future date, you can never select a date before that again!

Comment: Ok, I have installed moment and made the changes you said. However, I get quite a large error when I open the calendar. Could you show how you would implement moment into this calendar?

Comment: First, set the initial state as shown below.

```this.state = {date: moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY')};```

Then, your DatePicker would be something like this:

```<DatePicker
          style={{width: 200}}
          mode="date"
          date={this.state.date}
          format="DD-MM-YYYY"
          minDate={moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY')}
          maxDate="01-01-2030"
          confirmBtnText="Confirm"
          cancelBtnText="Cancel"
          onDateChange={d => {
            this.setState({date: d});
          }}
        />```