# Date object from parsed json to input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I am console.log() this:

```
console.log(value['startDate']);
```

and getting this:

[image]

I want to convert it in my jQuery method so I can input that value here:

[image]

I am quite new with jQuery and JavaScript in general so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is that input a `type="date"` field or are you using a library for it?

Comment: `value['startDate'].toLocaleDateString()` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#Examples

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format JavaScript date as yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: It's type="date" , yes. @EmielZuurbier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`<input type="date">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#value) has a property called `valueAsNumber` to which you can assign a timestamp like the one in your object.

The input will then do the heavy lifting for you and set the corresponding date.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

const value = {
  startDate: {
    offset: 0,
    timestamp: 1604966400,
    timezone: {}
  }
};

// This is where the magic happens.
input.valueAsNumber = value.startDate.timestamp;
```

```html
<input type="date">
```