# How to reverse fetch images from NASA APOD API in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

**I fetched content from API with this code:**

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./Space.module.css";

import {useState,useEffect} from "react";
function Space() {
  const [photoData,setPhotoData]=useState(null);
  useEffect(()=>{
fetchPhoto();
async function fetchPhoto(){
  const res = await fetch(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=hETQq0FPsZJnUP9C3sUEFtwmJH3edb4I5bghfWDM`);
  const data=await res.json();
  setPhotoData(data);
  console.log(data);
}
  },[]); //empty array for running only once then empty array for that 
 

  if (!photoData) return <div />;
  
  return (
    <>
    <div className={styles.space}>
      {photoData.media_type === "image" ? (
        <img 
          src={photoData.url}
          alt={photoData.title}
          className={styles.space}
        />
      ) : (
        <iframe
          title="space-video"
          src={photoData.url}
          frameBorder="0"
          gesture="media"
          allow="encrypted-media"
          allowFullScreen
          className={styles.space}
        />
      )}
      <div>
        <h1>{photoData.title}</h1>
        <p className={styles.space.date}>{photoData.date}</p>
        <p className={styles.space.explanation}>{photoData.explanation}</p>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    </>
  );
}
export default Space;
```

**and output of this code is like this:**

[image]

and I want Button here with next and then that will show previous day images.
So can anyone tell me how to reverse that means after clicking on the next button by reversing the previous day images will show because NASA APOD (astronomy picture of the day) daily shown to all users like that is updated daily I know we can reverse that, but can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: BTW, when asking questions in the future, it's probably best not to include your API keys or other sensitive information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `date` query parameter of apod api to get data for a specific date. This has default value `today`. Date needs to be in YYYY-MM-DD format. See apod section at https://api.nasa.gov/

If you want to request data for 2 January 2021 you'll have to send request to this :

```
https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?date=2021-01-02&api_key=hETQq0FPsZJnUP9C3sUEFtwmJH3edb4I5bghfWDM
```

<sub>Note the `date` parameter</sub>

To get the previous day date use :

```
let today = new Date();
let yesterday = new Date();

yesterday.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
console.log(yesterday.toString());
```

for formatting date in YYYY-MM-DD format see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd).

In `onClick` function of your button you'll make this http request and then change state with `setPhotoData` function.