# DateTime format in nodej.s

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

I get from API request the date in this format: 2021-03-18T15:08:52.000Z 
How can I convert it to this format: 2021-03-18 15:08:52

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format JavaScript date as yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: `new Date('2021-03-18T15:08:52.000Z').toLocaleString('defualt', {hour12: false}).replace(',','')` should work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use JavaScript [`substr`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) function to extracts specific parts of a string, *e.g.*:

```js
function convertDate(date) {
  return date && date.length == 24 ? date.substr(0, 10) + ' ' + date.substr(11, 8) : null;
}
let date1 = '2021-03-18T15:08:52.000Z';
let date2 = convertDate(date1);
console.log(date2);
```