# How to Extract Date from date stringg in JS

Tags: javascript

I want to know how to get a date from date string:

A string is expected to be formatted as follows:
YYYY-DD-MM

September 01, 2021 would be: 2021-01-09

it should be done using functions in Java Script.

Any answers??

And Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You'll want to make an attempt and  add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: you might be looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: As far as I understands, OP wants to do it the other way around.

Comment: Do you mean `new Date('2021-01-09')`?

Comment: Yeah. But unfortunately, they have day and month swapped... that is wrong in my answer.

Comment: Don't add the tag, `java` because `java != javascript`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this function it might help you.**

```js
function newDateFormat(date) {
    date = new Date(date);
    if(date == 'Invalid Date') return date;
    let month = date.getMonth();
    let day = date.getDate();
    return `${date.getFullYear()}-${day<10?'0':''}${day}-${month<10?'0':''}${month+1}`;
}
console.log(newDateFormat('September 01, 2021'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `new Date()` on your date string. Like so:

```
console.log(new Date('2012-01-12'));
```

Unfortunately for you, in your date format the month is in the end, but `new Date()` expects it in the middle. In that case, I would use a regular expression:

```js
var a = '2012-01-12'.match(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/);
console.log(new Date(a[1], a[3]-1, a[2]));
```

Note that here you have to subtract one from the month, since in JS January is month 0 etc.

Comment: It would return `2012-01-12T00:00:00.000Z` which OP doesn't want.

Comment: No, it returns a date object. The OP wants to parse a date string into a date object.
Only the snippet runtime converts it to this strange string.