# Format date to DD-MMM-YYYY in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, ecmascript-6, momentjs

There is an input of this format:

`2021-04-02T16:06:09.61`

How can it be formatted to be in `DD-MMM-YYYY` form?

For example, for the above input it should return `02-Apr-2021`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format JavaScript date as yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged your question with [momentjs](/questions/tagged/momentjs), so you can use the `format` method, like this:

```js
console.log(moment("2021-04-02T16:06:09.61").format("DD-MMM-YYYY"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

More info: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 1):

### in vanilla javascript

```js
const d = new Date();

let day = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { day: '2-digit' }).format(d);
let month = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: 'short' }).format(d);
let year = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric' }).format(d);

console.log(`${day} ${month} ${year}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```js
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
 
console.log(formatDate('Sun May 11,2014'));
```

copied from [Format JavaScript date as yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: If you're copying the answer to another question, then likely this is a duplicate so mark the question as a duplicate. :-)