# Substring in react

Tags: substring

I have a table like this

```html
<table className="table terms-table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>                                   
                                <th scope="col" >   start Date</th>
                                <th scope="col" >   end Date </th>

                           </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {termsData.map(term =>
                            (
                                <tr key={term._id}>
                                                                                                                             
                                   <td>
                                        {term.startDate}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        {term.endDate}
                                    </td>
                                   
                                </tr>
                            ))}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

and the date be like   1400-07-07T00:00:00.000Z

i just want 1400-07-07

how should i do this ?

Comment: Is `startDate`string or Date?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format JavaScript date as yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: I recommend using http://momentjs.com/ for date parsing and formatting. console.log(moment(Date.parse("1400-07-07T00:00:00.000Z")).format("YYYY-MM-DD"))

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this (assuming date is a String) is to use the `String`'s [`substring` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

```js
let date = "1400-07-07T00:00:00.000Z";
let newDate = date.substring(0, 10);
console.log('date is', date);
console.log('new date is', newDate);
```

If your date is already a javascript `Date` object, you can use the appropriate getters to get the data you want.

```js
let date = new Date();
let dateString = `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth()}-${date.getDate()}`;
console.log(dateString);
```