# Assign default value for a date type

Tags: angular

I use angular 10. I have a modal with a date input. I would like to assign today date.

In a component, I have

```
  addEventForm: FormGroup;
  addEventFormInitialValues = {
      eventType: ['', Validators.required],
      eventDate: ['', Validators.required]
  };
```

In the constructor I tried

```
  this.addEventFormInitialValues.eventDate = this.datepipe.transform(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

I get this error

> error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '(string |
> ((control: AbstractControl) => ValidationErrors))[]'.

I also tried

```
eventDate: [new Date(), Validators.required]
```

I don't get error but I don't have any default date displayed

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="eventDate" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">{{'addEvent.eventDate' | translate}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3 self-center">
        <input type='date' id="eventDate" formControlName="eventDate"/>
        <p class="no-bottom-margin">
                <app-form-validation-hint *ngIf="addEventSubmitted && eventAddForm.eventDate.errors && eventAddForm.eventDate.errors.required"></app-form-validation-hint>
        </p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `input` element with `type=date` expect the value to be a [valid date string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#value) in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`. So this would work:

```
addEventFormInitialValues = {
    eventType: ['', Validators.required],
    eventDate: [
      '2021-09-02',
      Validators.required
    ]
  };
```

but obviously it's not very handy to directly deal with dates in string format. You can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd) for how to format a JS `Date` as `yyyy-mm-dd`, but if you expect your application to do something more than trivial operations on dates I suggest you adopt a library such as [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/).

That being said, note that Angular doesn't come with a built in `ValueAccessor` for date inputs. When you write this:

`eventDate: [new Date(), Validators.required]`

your Angular form control gets indeed the default value. The point is, that value is not transcoded to a suitable format for the `input` element and that's why you don't see it there. Keeping your model date format and display date format in sync will probably require a custom `ValueAccessor`.

Answer (score 0):

You shuold use the format : 'yyyy-MM-dd'

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rtp8xl?file=src/app/reactive-form-dates-example.component.ts