# How to disable previous date using HTML5 datetime-local input?

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

I would simply like to prevent users from entering or disable the previous dates in input `datetime-local` , is there a way to do this?

Here is what I have done, unfortunately nothing happens on this code:

```html
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control col-md-6" name="book" required>
<script>
  var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
  document.getElementsByName('book')[0].setAttribute('min', today);
</script>
```

Comment: If you want the **local** date, don't use *toISOString* as that returns the UTC date, which will be ±1 day for users for the period of their local offset either side of midnight (which can be -10 to +14 hours). See [*Format JavaScript date as yyyy-mm-dd*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd).

Comment: The issue is that the value for [*DateTIme-local*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) must be YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm. The above trims the time (but it also uses the UTC date and time, not local so that needs to be fixed too).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```js
var today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 16);

document.getElementsByName("book")[0].min = today;
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control col-md-6" name="book" required>
```

Comment: I will try this one, thanks

Comment: That gets the current UTC date, not the local date so may be out by ±1 day depending on the current local time and offset.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label for="time_start">{{ __('adminstaticword.timestart') }}:<sup class="redstar">*</sup></label>
              <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="time_start" id="time_start" placeholder="Enter time_start" required min="{{date('Y-m-d')}}"  value="{{ old('time_start') }}" >
              <script>
                var today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 16);
                document.getElementsByName("time_start")[0].min = today;
                </script>
            </div>
```