# Limiting Date Picker (from today) - HTML

Tags: javascript, html, date, datetime, datepicker

I have been looking around on this page (among other forums) in search of an answer for limiting a date picker to 14 days from the day a user accesses the page. Built into the date picker is an option for 'todays date' which is auto configured and sets the date option to todays DD/MM/YY so I gather this can be achieved. What I aim for is **every date after 14 days from 'today' to be greyed out and not selectable**. I could further develop this so that no dates prior to 'today' can also be selected, but achieving a limit of 14 days after 'today' would be great for now.

I'm familiar with max-date and min-date which require a precise DD/MM/YY format setting boundaries between the listed dates. I require something like 'max-date: today + 14'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I require something like 'max-date: today + 14'

This is basically your answer, i.e. "set the max attribute to `today + 14` and the min attribute to `today`". Fairly straightforward to do in JavaScript:

```js
const datePicker = document.getElementById("date-picker");

datePicker.min = getDate();
datePicker.max = getDate(14);

// Borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29774197/7290573
function getDate(days) {
    let date;

    if (days !== undefined) {
        date = new Date(Date.now() + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    } else {
        date = new Date();
    }

    const offset = date.getTimezoneOffset();

    date = new Date(date.getTime() - (offset*60*1000));

    return date.toISOString().split("T")[0];
}
```

```html
<input id="date-picker" type="date" autocomplete="off" />
```