# How to Format Date to Complete YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS

Tags: javascript

Can you please take a look at this code and let me know how I can get the output in `YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS` format?

As you can see what I am getting now is `2022-04-22` which is `YYYY-MM-DD`

```js
const d = new Date();
var dStr = new Date(d.getTime() - (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString().split("T")[0];

console.log(dStr);
```

Comment: You can use the `getHours`, `getMinutes`, and `getSeconds` methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I format a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: [What is the "right" JSON date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/what-is-the-right-json-date-format?r=SearchResults&s=2|416.7401)

Comment: [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript?r=SearchResults&s=3|411.1889)

Comment: [Format JavaScript date as yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd?r=SearchResults&s=5|280.1472)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS format like this:

```
new Date(d.getTime() - (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString().split(".")[0].replace(/[T:]/g, '-')
```

Explanation:

- `.split(".")[0]` removes the dot near the end and everything after it.
- `.replace(/[T:]/g, '-')` changes the `T` and the colons (`:`) to dashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const value = new Date().toLocaleString('sv-SE').replace(/[\s\:]/g, '-')
console.log(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simplified way to do is:

```js
const date = new Date().toLocaleDateString('pt-BR',{ year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit'}).split( '/' ).reverse( ).join( '-' );

const time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString('pt-BR',{ hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' });

console.log(date +" "+ time);
//2023-10-07 12:35
```