# Get ISO date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a Date object. Is there a simpler way to get the `YYYY-MM-DD` format than doing the following?

```js
let val = new Date(2014,1,1);
console.log(val.toJSON().split('T')[0]);
```

Comment: `val.toJSON().slice(0,10)` Be aware that this will give UTC date, not local date. That can be different at some points in time.

Comment: Please do basic research before asking, e.g. there are 52 (!) answers to this at https://stackoverflow.com/q/23593052/3001761.

Comment: @trincot are there any differences between `.toISOString()` and `toJSON()` in the above ?

Comment: No, there aren't. `toJSON` uses `toISOString`.

Comment: [_"Calling `toJSON()` returns a string (using `toISOString()`)..."_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON#description)