# Disabling the dates according to previous date selection

Tags: javascript, html, .net, asp.net-core

I'm new to JavaScript. So please don't go harsh on me.

After the StartDate gets selected, the ExpectedEndDate and the EndDate must start with StartDate + 1 day and end in 6 months. Other dates must be disabled in the ExpectedEndDate and EndDate.

Here the futureInput.Max works fine. But the futureInput.Min doesn't work. I couldn't find where it went wrong.

```
$(document).ready(()=>{

                var startInput = $('#StartDate')[0];
                var expectedEndInput = $('#ExpectedEndDate')[0];
                var endInput = $('#EndDate')[0];

                startInput.addEventListener('change', (evt)=>{
                    
                    var EndTime = new Date($("#StartDate").val());
                    var dd = String(EndTime.getDate() + 1);
                    var mm = String(EndTime.getMonth() + 6);
                    var yyyy = EndTime.getFullYear();

                    var MaxTime = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

                    var StartTime = new Date($("#StartDate").val());
                    var dd = String(StartTime.getDate() + 1);
                    var mm = String(StartTime.getMonth() + 1);
                    var yyyy = StartTime.getFullYear();

                    var MinTime = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

                    debugger
                    [expectedEndInput, endInput].forEach((futureInput)=> {
                    futureInput.min = MinTime;
                    futureInput.max = MaxTime;
                    debugger
                    })
                    
                })
            })
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>



<input type="date" id="StartDate" />
<input type="date" id="ExpectedEndDate" />
<input type="date" id="EndDate" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to react to every change of the `<input id="StartDate">`, we need to set a `change` event listener for it.

```js
function daysToMilliseconds(days) {
    return days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
}

function millisecondsToDateString(milliseconds) {
    // to convert Date to yyyy-mm-dd use Swedish locale
    return new Date(milliseconds).toLocaleDateString('sv-SE');
}

$(document).ready(()=>{

  var startInput = $('#StartDate')[0];
  var expectedEndInput = $('#ExpectedEndDate')[0];
  var endInput = $('#EndDate')[0];
  
  startInput.addEventListener('change', (evt)=>{
    // called every time the startInput's date value changes
  
    // get start date as milliseconds since 1970 New Year
    var startTime = startInput.valueAsNumber;
    
    // startDate + 1 day
    var minTime = startTime + daysToMilliseconds(1);
    // startDate + 180 days (6 months)
    var maxTime = startTime + daysToMilliseconds(30 * 6);
    
    [expectedEndInput,endInput].forEach((futureInput)=> {
      futureInput.min = millisecondsToDateString(minTime);
      futureInput.max = millisecondsToDateString(maxTime);
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="StartDate" />
<input type="date" id="ExpectedEndDate" />
<input type="date" id="EndDate" />
```

Refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd#answer-69737382) for conversion of Date objects to yyyy-mm-dd.
Only values of yyyy-mm-dd are accepted for input date `min` & `max`.