# React MultiDatePicker changing date format sent to the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I'm using MultiDatePicker to send multiple dates to my server, the console.log(date) show it in the intended format (2022/08/08) but when it is sent you get something like the next data, any help on sending the data on format yyyy/mm/dd or anything similar would be appreciated

```
"startingDate": [
1659934800000,
1661922000000,
1661317200000,
1661749200000,
1661058000000,
1660453200000,
1661230800000
],
```

```
import DatePicker, { DateObject } from "react-multi-date-picker";
import DatePanel from "react-multi-date-picker/plugins/date_panel"

const date = new DateObject().format()
const [startingDate, setStartingDate] = useState(date);

console.log(startingDate)
console.log(date)

<DatePicker 
  value={startingDate} 
  onChange={setStartingDate} 
  multiple
  name="startingDate"
  plugins={[
    <DatePanel />
  ]} />
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of format `1659934800000` for date is `Date Format in milliseconds`.
To change this format into real Date format, you can simply call `new Date(1659934800000)`.

Then with this date object, you can format to your specific needs. For more detailed docs, please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd).