# How to serialize Date and DateTime with URQL?

Tags: graphql, urql

I am using urql-react as my React client in a project. I need to make sure that any date variables in query/mutation with `Date` scalar type are serialized into `YYYY-DD-MM` format while for DateTime scalar type, the date object is serialized in `YYYY-DD-MMTHH:mm:ssZ` format.

How can this be achieved on a central level?

Comment: Just [format it as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29774197/2805154) before passing it to the mutation.

Comment: @MichelFloyd - Thanks. I am actually looking for a centralized mechanism. I have edited my question now.

Comment: No answer to this quesiton yet?