# Cannot change datetime format to the way i want

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to change format of datetime command format in c#

```
Lbldate.content = DateTime.Now.Tostring();
```

The result is 11/3/2022
But i want it to show me 2022/11/03

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `ToString` without parameters, the system default format will be used, whatever that might be. It will be different on different systems, depending on culture and user settings. If you want a specific format then you need to pass the appropriate format specifier when calling `ToString`. It appears that you want this:

```cs
Lbldate.content = DateTime.Now.Tostring("yyyy/MM/dd");
```

You should read up about standard and custom format strings for dates, times and numbers.

Comment: I know this but surprisingly it was not working because i had missing type haha lol... And also you so mean guys...   