# String date to format in another type of format JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, format

I need a way to parse string date to another format string or date

```
Tuesday, December 28, 2022   this string date into that format    2022-12-28
```

I can make it with hardcoding but I think it is not the best way, any good ideas on how I can format that string?

Comment: convert to Date() and get the month date and year using getMonth() and so on and then concatenate strings

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-as-yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The way to parse string date to another format string or date like this 2022-12-28 is:**

```
function dateFormat(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
 
console.log(dateFormat('Sun Dec 12,2022'));
```

Comment: hello before of everything thank you, you put so much effort to answer my question. I am trying now :)

Comment: This exactly worked for me thank you so much!!