# How to convert date string which contains time offset to another format?

Tags: javascript, date, utc, datetimeoffset

I'm receiving this kind of string as date "2020-09-09T12:41:41 -04:00".
It seems like this string contains time offset.
I need to convert this to "3/15/2020, 1:23:09 PM " format.
How can I achieve this?

I tried to create new Date object with that string but it shows me Invalid Date.

Comment: Do you have code that you can share?

Comment: Those dates are completely different. How do you expect the conversion to happen?

Comment: Remove the space: `new Date("2020-09-09T12:41:41-04:00")` works fine

Comment: Once you've converted to a date, use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-javascript) for various methods to provide an output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [INTL DateTime format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) after you remove the illegal space

```js
const d = new Date("2020-09-09T12:41:41-04:00")
console.log(d)

const options = {
  year: "numeric",
  month: "numeric",
  day: "numeric",
  hour : "numeric",
  minute : "numeric",
  second : "numeric",
};
const dateString = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", options).format(d);
console.log(dateString);
```

Alternatively have full control

```js
const toAMPM = hhmmss => {
  const [hours, minutes, seconds] = hhmmss.split(":");
  const formatHours = hours % 12 || 12;
  const ampm = hours < 12 ? "AM" : "PM";
  return `${+formatHours}:${minutes}:${seconds} ${ampm}`;
};
const convertTime = dateString => {
  const d = new Date(dateString).toISOString();
  const [_, yyyy, mm, dd, time] = d.match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\./);
  return `${+mm}/${+dd}/${yyyy}, ${toAMPM(time)}`;
};

console.log(convertTime("2023-02-28T12:41:41-04:00"));
```

Comment: While en-us is likely pretty stable, it's not a good idea in general to use *Intl.DateTimeFormat* where precise formatting is required. Recently, the format for language en-ca changed from y-MM-DD to M/d/y (reflecting a change by the CLDR) much to the [annoyance of some on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75562129/why-is-date-locale-en-ca-returning-m-d-yyyy-instead-of-yyyy-mm-dd#comment133315993_75562129). Apparently this was [an error](https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/CLDR-16399), but it shows that the formatting is somewhat whimsical.